# Supercollider message: "Your resume was viewed wants to contact you"

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, grammar

A slight grammar error in the supercollider when my resume has been viewed:

> **Your Resume was Viewed** wants to contact you on **Stack Overflow Careers**

[image: **Your Resume was Viewed** wants to contact you on **Stack Overflow Careers**]

Comment: You haven't heard of them?  They just got funding from They Might Be Giants. (stolen)

Comment: Congrats on having s stellar resume :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed.  Thanks for pointing this out.