# The new top bar is out on meta. Consider it a beta

Tags: discussion, global-inbox, top-bar, feedback

**EDIT Dec 4 -  We're doing it live! Please post bugs or concerns as questions tagged [top-bar]**

We have rolled out our 95% completed top bar for feedback.

Note:

- We are still adding a few final features, so if you have a request for a feature that is not there you might hold off on that for a day or two
- Yes, the bar is black<sup>1</sup>. Also give that a day or two to sink in.

I also want to specifically address the meta/main/chat links.

I'm very aware that many of you like having the links at the top of the page and that this new version is different.

The thought process behind moving these links is that the "site switcher" should be an automatic place to go when you are on a site and want to go to another one. If you haven't already developed the muscle memory for these links, getting between them required a bit of a cognitive load: You must first decide that you want to switch sites and then you have to decide which area to go to to switch.

Also, we find that less familiar users aren't entirely clear what a standalone link that says "main" or "meta" actually does... Not to mention that it hurts my UX sensibilities that we are dynamically changing links in an element that should be fixed.

It is true that we have added a click in the process, but we have also removed a lot of clicks for other common actions that are much more frequent than switching between main and meta.

All I ask is that you give it a few days and see if the new "switch sites at the top left" paradigm grows on you.

What do you think?

<sup>1. [Jin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin) points out that *technically* it's not quite black.</sup>

Comment: Little bit of a shock initially :-).

Comment: Where's the hot questions?

Comment: @Mysticial Hot questions are moving to the homepage sidebar. Stay tuned for that next week.

Comment: Inbox is missing a tooltip; I assume that's coming?

Comment: I.. I... I am in love with it. thank you

Comment: @David yup, #212121 is not black. It's [Gray13](http://www.color-hex.com/color/212121). ;)

Comment: Erm... Where is my inbox?

Comment: @RobertHarvey [The envelope.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope)

Comment: nvm, found it.  Boy is that dark... it's like a shadow of a shadow.

Comment: That is an envelope? I thought it was a headset at first :P

Comment: @TravisJ you're both wrong, it's actually a literal inbox in perspective.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it lights up when there's something to see

Comment: Cool.  I like it so far.

Comment: @DavidFullerton - Your ping showed up right in there. That was kind of neat.

Comment: @RobertHarvey [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jnful.png) :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArdL http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta#comment660230_207420

Comment: @RobertHarvey you called [my sock](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/206610/shadow-of-the-shadow)?

Comment: On a whole, this is awesome! Thanks, Jeremy/Jin/Laura!

Comment: Yeah, this is really cool. Feels well thought through and looks good

Comment: It's pretty sleek but it would be nice if you could filter on achievement types, badges get drowned in rep

Comment: thankyouthankyouthankyou :D

Comment: CW in 3... 2... 1...

Comment: Fix to the list of sites is good, but only 4 of them? I would like at least ten before it switches to the alphabetical order remainders. Or probably "everything over 200" like the rep graph does.

Comment: I'm embarrassed how giddy it makes me seeing the green rep indicator light up when I get upvotes.

Comment: I'd prefer my username make a comeback and replace the teeny tiny gravatar. You can't really see the image very well anyway.

Comment: @WendiKidd We had a length problem with some people's usernames

Comment: @JeremyTunnell Ahh, I see! Well, that makes sense :) The only other comment I really have is that the text in the inbox is *super* hard to read. I have to squint and it kind of hurts my eyes. I can read the bold text just fine; it's thicker, and I think maybe darker? But the regular type seems kind of blurry. Other than that I like the new design; I think others are right that the icons could be a lighter shade of grey, but that's a small thing. Great work!

Comment: Oh! I just got my first new inbox notification on the new top bar. Okay, whatever style is used for the regular font when the inbox notification is *unread*, I can read that just fine. It's the *old* notifications I have to squint for. I agree with others that it's a bit hard to tell the difference between them, so maybe experiment with keeping the font the same and changing something else to differentiate? /just some thoughts

Comment: @WendiKidd I tend to agree and we will talk it over tomorrow

Comment: Wait, will this be (off-)black on **every** site? Even established sites whose color schemes were carefully decided upon long ago and for which a black bar is quite jarring?

Comment: @ChrisWhite - I addressed that here : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200317/178816 . It would seem that every site will have the blackish bar on top.

Comment: @TravisJ I wish I had known about it earlier to upvote, as the entire page is now locked :(

Comment: Does anyone know where the privileges link is?

Comment: @AndreSilva I don't know where it was *before*.... I always manually typed in /privileges because I didn't know where to find that link.

Comment: @WendiKidd, thanks. That was useful!

Comment: I do that too, @Wendi, just because I don't like the extra click to get a drop-down. Even though the canonical URL isn't /privileges anymore...

Comment: @JeremyTunnell - Re: [ref missing name](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207431/178816). Wouldn't it be possible to just truncate excessively long user names just like is done on the rest of the site in situations where they are too long (i.e. like in chat)?

Comment: I really like it! Although I will say initially I didn't think the envelope icon was... well an envelope at all. Maybe make it a closed envelope icon?

Comment: Side note: what's the plan for the mobile site?

Comment: Now that this is CW I don't think we get notified of comments on our answers, right? Any chance of changing it back to a regular post at least until the beta period is over, so we can follow our discussions a bit more easily (and have more replies in our inboxes to mess around with the new header bar system? :))

Comment: @wendikidd, I un-wiki'd everything but the deleted answers.

Comment: Could we make the `.topbar` something like `background-color: #444` instead?

Comment: This is so confusing,

Comment: I liked the older, cleaner one.

Comment: Can we make it a little less-black to match the overall theme of MSO?

Comment: Also, will this thing be rolling out for all the sites on SE or just all the meta sites of the SE network?

Comment: @R.J All sites, MSO is where this stuff gets tested out.

Comment: Is the default gravitar background color configurable?  If so, having it be white kind of clashes with the black bar and makes it look weird.

Comment: Is top bar color configurable ?? if not then please change its color to lighter side not this dark .. it is very hard to see the icons in the back color

Comment: I really like the new top bar. I might just stay on meta until it gets rolled out on every else. Also, if I comment on this question maybe I'll get to see how the new notifications work *wink wink* :).

Comment: I don't mind dark, but this is just too dark.

Comment: @Jaydles I'm assuming everything is re-wiki-ing every time a new answer is posted

Comment: Will this new bar contain the help link even on sites you are not a member of; as per [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191107/give-the-about-and-help-pages-a-more-prominent-location-for-anonymous-users)?

Comment: Hmm. I, too, am still waiting to see how notifications look, @MatthewGreen.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen It's pretty nice. :) Though it doesn't seem to be using ajax. I had to reload the page before I saw I had a notification. I don't remember that being the case with the old one.

Comment: Looks good, I like it :)

Comment: Absolutely Love it :) Cant wait before it gets to SO

Comment: I'm glad you released it. It was really hard to give feedback on a mockup. NOW STOP MOVING MY CHEESE.

Comment: @MatthewGreen I'll ping you if you ping me back... I'm super curious to see what it looks like.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I do notice it doesn't load the same (in real time) as the old one did. Hopefully that is a fix that they plan as part of the roll out.

Comment: @MatthewGreen I had to reload to see it as well. That's a little disappointing.

Comment: Looks really nice! Much more intuitive

Comment: ["I wanna see it painted, painted black..."](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1zBG2TEjn4 "Rolling Stones")

Comment: IMO #444 looks better than the #212121 being used for the "black" background.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell re putting hot questions on the main-page sidebar, please don't clobber the recent-badges list.  That's really useful for noticing questions that are getting activity, users who are increasing participation in certain ways, etc.  Maybe none of that matters on huge sites, but on smaller ones where community-building is really important, I find that quite important.  (OTOH, if the list of recent tags went away I wouldn't care at all.)

Comment: It's tough to really evaluate it because I can only use it in one direction, and I spend more time on main and dba.se (and switching between those two sites) than on meta.

Comment: @RJ that's the whole point, this top bar is not for meta, it's for all sites. It's just being rolled out here first, hopefully to work out some kinks and add some fit & finish.

Comment: I find the dark gray on black (or whatever it is) nearly invisible; the contrast needs to be *much* higher. And the envelope icon doesn't particularly look like an envelope.

Comment: The new bar is awesome! I truely love it :) Needs some development, but since its a beta, its ok..:)

Comment: Super low contrast ftl...

Comment: You should post this on http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Knu It's just too big to fit as a question on UX

Comment: You should add transparency to identicons cause mine looks really ugly on the new top bar.

Comment: When is the new topbar going to be added to the other sites?  Days? Weeks?  Months?

Comment: The design is very nice, but the color combinations choice is bad from an accessibility POV: that faint gray over black is hard to see. I guess it could be a real problem with people with some degree of vision impairment. I find it very eye-straining (and I'm not visually impaired).

Comment: I guess there isn't a mobile beta... :/

Comment: @JeffMercado No, but there are upcoming mobile apps!  I'd like to do a mobile version, but it's just a bit lower priority.

Comment: @SuperScript Right now it's looking like late next week.

Comment: So far, I've found that everything I normally do takes more clicks than it did before, and nothing that I wasn't able to do before has been made possible. The previously fine UI was made less effective (maybe this is just for my usage?) with no benefit that I can see. It was a very Google-like move... Also the dark background with gray foreground is a bit hard on the eyes, and changes the vibe (to me) from the old cozy meta to one of those random e.g. blogger sites that serve no purpose other than to be a web designer's portfolio piece.

Comment: @SuperScript Hopefully never.

Comment: I've gotta say, I really like the new top bar a lot.   I'm actually looking forward to seeing it on the other sites (like SO).

Comment: @Jaydles and Jeremy, can we please get to know the developers behind the scenes, working to bring life to this idea? I remember the android app devs got listed somewhere.

Comment: Why does the *recent reputation and achievement* not show the post immediately, but just the reputation gain value? It is after sometime and a couple of refreshes that the post by which the reputation gain happened is actually listed in it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, no.  Jeremy and I prefer to take all the credit, rather than share it with the actual *creators* who build these things.  Okay, fine - the HARD work on this one was mostly done by jarroddixon and nickcraver, plus some special teams work by balpha. On the design side, as usual, magic was made by jin.

Comment: @Jaydles cheers, this is indeed elite group!

Comment: Rwar I just noticed now that I can no longer click on my reputation to go to my Reputation page. That's my most commonly used item on the header, and the dropdown just isn't the same :(

Comment: @Rachel what about [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9y89m.png)? The rep change in the Achievements box links to the relevant reputation tab. :)

Comment: Any ETA for upgrading the stackoverflow toolbar?

Comment: Update on the timeline, folks: Most of the bugs are squished. I'm told the live rep and inbox numbers will be a little shaky until we stop running both top bars in parallel.  We've got an inbox formatting refresh and a help drop-down to put in, but the current plan is to go live on the network Friday... Unless someone pushes the big red button to abort.

Comment: The search box in the search box doesn't expand when typing. Is it my imagination that it used to do that? I know SO does it.

Comment: Initially I had mixed feelings about the colour of the new bar, but now all I see on the other sites is an ugly top bar :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd But but but it's not the same! It requires two clicks, and mixes in rep and achievements from other sites too! Woe is me

Comment: @Rachel many things are now an extra click away, but still there, e.g. my beloved "main" link. We'll survive! ;)

Comment: @JeremyTunnell thanks, I took the liberty to embed this into the post instead of being just buried deep down here in the comments.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd =O Wait where's my main/meta links?? Now how am I supposed to visit the meta site.... ooohh the tragedy.... to have to type it in by hand or find some link burried in another menu... aren't toolbars supposed to be useful with the most commonly used links immediately available? :p

Comment: @Rachel Just use the "site switcher" i.e. click the "StackExchange" and you can reach all sites from there. ;)

Comment: @j08691 [not your imagination](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIrcyU7Zk-c) - feel free to post answer here or new feature request to ask to bring back the cool effect. :)

Comment: I just noticed a new dialog for the help center. Nice one! But Help Center links to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta instead of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/ is it by design?

Comment: @hims056 Yes, by design on meta sites.  That page is more relevant than all the other pages which are really generally applicable to the whole network.

Comment: @Jeremy Did someone push the big red button?

Comment: @yoda From above: New update on the timeline: Unfortunately, we are pushing the red button. We have had a number of edge case bugs pop up over the last couple of days. We've got a plan to fix them, which won't take very long, but next week is a big holiday week and most of the team is out. That means the launch is going to have to be after the holiday weekend. Bad timing, but it's important to make sure this is polished before it goes out to the whole network.

Comment: Have you guys tested on sites that have implemented their own top bar, like [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)? Or will they not be part of the global rollout?

Comment: So, out of idle curiosity, is `not quite black` one of those newfangled named-in-the-CSS-specification colors? :) (I would read the CSS specs and find out for myself, but the last time I opened that file Hastur came out of my monitor and started hitting me...)

Comment: Not sure if this is worth posting a new meta post for, but your quotes aren't parsed properly in the new drop down. My achievement came through as *" 
You&#39;ve earned the &quot;Notable Question&quot; badge for How can I get the correct offset between UTC and local times for a date that is before or after DST?. See your profile"*

Comment: @JeremyTunnell I noticed the "Hot Network Questions" is out, on all sites... does it mean the top bar launch is fast approaching? :)

Comment: Tomorrow! Pending a bug inventory in the morning.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell awesome!   Looking forward to seeing the bar on other sites.

Answer (score 111):

Please add back the profile-hover-quick-view thingy:

[image: Thingy]

I actively use it to monitor the day/week/month rep, rep breakdown, and UTC time. The quick link to privileges is nice too, when I need to check/link to them.

**Note**: there is a "workaround" by manually navigating to `http://[site]/users/profile-link-stats` e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/profile-link-stats but it's not formatted very nicely.

Comment: I doubt the dropdown will be coming back - the other dropdowns are intended to replace it. But we do need the UTC time somewhere.

Comment: Just remember that touch screen users can't "hover".

Comment: @AnnaLear what about the vote count? I find that pretty handy...

Comment: @chuex No, but you can tap the triangle. I still use it on my tablets. To be fair, it's not a big hit target.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Then where is the link to the priviledges?

Comment: @AnnaLear I see now that there is rep-by-question in the... right-most left-hand box, but it would still be nice to get the day/week/month summary, maybe on top of that pulldown.

Comment: @Kevin We'd like to be able to do that, but the way we had to aggregate across sites it's just not possible for us to get the day/week/month roll ups with the performance we would need.

Comment: @AnnaLear This is a better place for either the rep changes or the badges.  They shouldn't be in the same "menu", as the rep changes drown out the badges.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Privileges are relatively handily linked from the help center.

Comment: @AnnaLear "relatively" being the key word there.

Comment: Loss of real-time vote count is a huge problem for me.

Comment: Please, for the love of god, put this back. I can't believe the two main posts requesting this dropdown be added back have both been dismissed as "doubt[ing] the dropdown will be coming back."

Comment: At first I wanted too. After several days with the new design I got used to it and it's actually... cleaner.

Comment: @davidsleeps see the edit, your counts are still available. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear I see you added UTC time in the top right of Achievements box - nice! :)

Answer (score 104):

Can the sorting of the sites be by title first, then description?

When I start typing "Physics", I would expect Physics and Physical Fitness to top the list, not Astronomy. Most of us would search by site name, not description:

[image]

Sure, it takes a few extra seconds to type, but it could be improved :)

Update: This also completely excludes Ham.SE from the search if you type "Ham" and not "Amateur Radio".

Perhaps it should filter by site name and URL only? Or at least give sitename/URL matches priority?

Comment: I think it is done this way, at least in part, because of Cross-Validated (which will come up if you type in "stat").  It works the same way as the Moderator Migration dialog's search.  Nobody searches for "cross" if they're looking for a statistics site, unless they already know the name of the site.

Comment: Also "apple" for "Ask Different."

Comment: @RobertHarvey Then do it by the site name+url. That's an easy fix. [This script of mine](http://stackapps.com/questions/3513/super-multicollider-dropdown-search) did just that.

Comment: It already does that.  You can search for "Ask Different".  So you just want a re-sort of the results?  I can get behind that, I guess.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, a re-sort would work, but it currently doesn't sort by URL, it sorts by name+description. Case in point: Search "Ham".

Comment: Why would you sort by the URL?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Why would you sort by the description? Same reason, just that the URL seems better to me since the description has more (possibly irrelevant) words in it. And again, case in point, Ham.SE.

Comment: Y'know, if you'd finished typing the `s` on the end of that search, we wouldn't even be having this lovely conversation. :)  And the "ham" example could be solved by putting "ham radio" in the description.

Comment: @RobertHarvey LOL. That works, though the issue really is there for `phys` too. Ideally `p` or `ph` should bring it up but somehow the English language seems to like that letter combination :P

Comment: I think the main idea behind this is that matches in the *title* should be given a higher priority than matches in the description.

Comment: No, you cannot. You **really** want to go to Astronomy.

Comment: This is fixed by a build rolling out now.

Answer (score 92):

I wish my face were a little bigger.  (On my avatar, not in real life.)

It makes me happy to see it staring at me up there, but it looks squished, and like there's probably room to expand a few pixels in each direction?

[image: small avatar]

Could it be embiggened?

[image: big avatar]

Comment: Also, using a white background on my meta image worked for the (white-backed) profile page, but ends up being a little white box in the header.

Comment: @Shog9, my thoughts exactly :)

Comment: That, definitely. Also, a very faint border, glow or shadow to distinct it better from the underlying background.

Comment: You could probably do away with the icon entirely, if you had to.  I already know what mine looks like.

Comment: Yep 18 pixels are way too tiny by all means. Better off without it, can't see anything in such a small scale anyway.

Comment: That might look ugly for some. Though if you give it a small border, that would work. Then again, what Robert says makes sense, the only reason I would want to see my gravatar is so that I am reminded of which sockpuppet I'm browsing with. (Well, TBH the icon is good UX from the new user POV)

Comment: I like your face too! The icon isn't meant for making out what the picture is. You know what it is. It's your gravatar after all. Even if we made it full height of the top bar, it may not be adequate enough for some users' photos. The small gravatar here is a replacement for your user name, a way to show that you're in fact logged in and a hit box to link to your user profile page.

Comment: You have green face.

Comment: Embiggen; it's a perfectly cromulent word.

Answer (score 85):

Can you **PLEASE** put the "main" link back on top?

I always switch between "main" and "meta" using it, now I'm at a great loss.

OK, found it:

> [image]

But still, I have to perform a full mouse click to reach it! :(

---

Edit by Undo: For the time being, I've created a nice little userscript to add the main link back in. **It's available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Undo1/SE-Topbar-MainMeta).**

Comment: (Repeating [my comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta?noredirect=1#comment660190_207421) here) Try getting used to the site switcher. After playing with it internally for a few weeks, I think it's much easier to have all the site switching links in one place.

Comment: @DavidFullerton that involves an **extra** click that is not needed...

Comment: @DavidFullerton: I'd argue with that. It's a lot harder to find now, especially considering that the like in the switcher doesn't even say main or meta.

Comment: @David same mistake Microsoft made with Windows 8 by hiding the Start button away. You know how it ended. :)

Comment: FWIW, I didn't find it difficult to find—I like the cleaner top bar...

Comment: With a useless button re-added? Good @Sha, assure me that I yet may change these shadows you have shown me, by an altered life... I will honor Christmas in my heart, and try to keep it all the year!

Comment: @DavidFullerton The site switcher take 5 seconds to load; it has an extra POST request attached to it.

Comment: I liked chat on the main bar too. I do like the collider drop-downs a lot better, but I don't want to go into those for main/meta and chat.

Comment: @Shog9 Precisely! People complained about the start button missing, and that's what Microsoft fixed. What they were really complaining about was the start *menu*.

Comment: @David, Shog - the site switcher was super convenient on a tablet. One tap instead of tap, wait, process, mis-tap, back button, repeat.  Maybe you could bring it back for tablets?

Comment: @Shog9 seriously now, did you by chance record the usage in the "main" link, maybe be analysing the referrer? If you say less than 10% of users ever used it I'll silently bow my head down and accept my fate. :)

Comment: That'd be a question for Jeremy, @Sha. Personally, I don't care how many people used it - I just don't want any *fewer* people using it. Or more people emailing us instead of using it. But there's no way to know how that'll pan out but to try it - so try it we will.

Comment: I want my **main** back!

Comment: From an [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207425/162102) that was deleted as a dupe (simultaneous post, but not the same): We have trouble getting people to participate on per-site metas to begin with (at least on some sites) and this change (removing the link) makes it that extra bit more obscure. Plus, I use it all the time (because I do participate on per-site metas).

Comment: @MonicaCellio: Jeremy has a point; the only ones who know what that bare link means are the veterans, and they already know how to get there anyway.

Comment: @Robert not in my case. As a new user I clicked it to see what it is and the rest is history. :)

Comment: **[Link to a userscript on GitHub to put the link back!](https://github.com/Undo1/SE-Topbar-MainMeta)**

Comment: @Undo hurry, add it on http://stackapps.com/!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Doing so.

Comment: @Undo cheers, when you do feel free to edit my post adding this as a workaround. (Looks like we won't get it back)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Done and done.

Comment: Real-time forking of a beta feature.  I like it.  We should have just called this post "Who moved my cheese?"

Comment: Coincidence that @Undo did the undo?

Comment: I don't think this is "who moved my cheese" but after playing with it on a tablet it's not a huge deal

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm surprised nobody wrote a script to bring the envelope back! :P

Comment: @DavidFullerton: It's hard to know how well I like the new site-switcher to togglgle between meta and main until there are both meta and main sites using the new site-switcher...

Comment: Y'all should make a lightweight switcher that comes up on hover and only load that monstrously large thing when we click. You've already got that little triangle/arrow sitting there doing nothing; you can have it rotate when you click to access the full menu (which should basically never happen for non-power users).

Comment: I happen to really like it, so if this goes well with the So Meta community, will you push to all Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: I think keyboard shortcuts (like Twitter) would make power users satisfied without having to change the interface.

Comment: @Wold think you meant to post this comment on the main question? :)

Comment: @Calle you mean keyboard shortcut to navigate between main and meta?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I don't personally do it that much so I don't need it. But I just meant that adding buttons just for power users may not be the way to go. On Twitter only a few of the actions you can take via keyboard shortcuts is readily available through buttons (g u, go to user; g m; go to messages etc). I kinda like it.

Comment: Despite initial rage this seems fine after a few minutes, and Meta is probably not used often by most users

Comment: @Calle Hiding the link like this hurts power users, too - possibly more than regular users.  I have hotkeys that let me follow any link using solely the keyboard (so switching between main and meta is a simple `fmeta<enter>` or `fmain<enter>`, but after this alteration it won't be so easily accessible.

Comment: @Manishearth we now pre-load the most important top section with the page, AJAXing in the rest, this at least makes the switch have no load delay.

Comment: @NickCraver Yay, thanks!

Comment: I've also noticed the lack of a `main` link(and presumably a `meta` link if this gets released to meta sites).  I liked that link.  I used it often.

Answer (score 81):

> [image: SE top bar: drop-downs vs. links]

*… but they look the same.*

The top bar consists of three different kinds of "actions":

- **drop-downs** (staying on the same page)
- **links** (leading to a different page)
- **input form** (leading to a different page)

The StackExchange drop-down has this little triangular icon, which makes it obvious that it’s not a link but a drop-down. But such an indicator is missing for the two other drop-downs (inbox, recent reputation).

Possible solutions:

- add a triangular icon for the inbox and the recent reputation actions, too
- change the style (or at least the hover style) for the two links (user avatar, help), making it look more like links instead of drop-downs
- make the links drop-downs, too (e.g., quick user menu links for the avatar; help page links for the help)

Comment: We've had long, long conversations about these issues. I'm convinced there's no perfect solution, but the triangle on the logo is necessary because usually the logo goes to the homepage and isn't a drop down. I've generally oppose adding triangles to the two other icons strictly from a aesthetics perspective. The help link will soon be a drop-down also, but I don't think we need a triangle there because the user won't really need to know that he gets additional choices until he clicks. Basically, nobody is going to skip over it because there's no triangle there.

Comment: @JeremyTunnel: Yes, I wouldn’t recommend adding a triangle to every action. If the help link will become a drop-down, then there is only one link left: the avatar+rep+medal thing. Make it a drop-down, too, so that every "link" in this top bar behaves in the same way.

Comment: @JeremyTunnel I just hope whichever option you end up with that it will be consistent, all drop downs have a triangle or not, having a mix seems the worst solution. The logo drop down isn't special in any case and one would expect other drop downs to have one if that one has one.

Comment: Or, maybe make the dropdown triangle fade in on hover, that way at least it will look consistent while the top bar isn't being used.

Comment: Seeing what the UX folks say http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/48177/how-to-handle-consistency-when-the-meaning-of-the-word-isntconsistent

Comment: @JeremyTunnell I bet you saw this while there : http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11519/drop-down-consistency-needed-on-navigation-on-site-header

Comment: I think "make the links drop-downs" is a bad idea. I don't want to click twice just to watch my profile.

Answer (score 50):

The link to the list of sites, which I use very occasionally, is about 140 pixels wide and in a nice accessible location near the left margin (though for some reason not flush left).

The link to the inbox, which I use very often, is about 35 pixels wide and awkwardly located in a middling location.

The inbox also suffers from being an unrecognizable graphic (how about making this a mailbox? or an envelope?) when there are no unread messages, though I suppose users will quickly get used to its location.

This is backward. It's a major drop in usability from the former inbox access which had the inbox as a nice wide button and the first thing on the left (though for some reason not flush left either) whenever messages were pending.

[image: left part of the top bar]

Please make the inbox button wider. It really needs to be wider than the site list since it's more useful, at least when there are unread messages.

I'm unsure about the achievements button (which also has an unrecognizable graphic — is that a bar chart? What does this have to do with achievements?) since I don't know yet what use that list is.

On a similar note, the inbox has a worse contrast than the achievement list. I see the reputation thingy tick away with three characters (soon 4) in bright green that seems poised to assault me, while the inbox is usually a lonesome digit and is in a darkish shade of red that seems to try to stay lurking in its dark alley.

[image: inbox vs achievements]

Comment: An [envelope](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope), you say?

Comment: @Shog9 It's more evocative than a… a… a gray thingy.

Comment: IMHO, it's become one of those things like using a floppy to represent "save" that folks recognize the purpose of without having to recognize what it's meant to *be*. That said, it *was* an envelope [in the mockups](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198613/feedback-request-new-top-bar-and-multicollider-redesign), so I have to assume there was some rationale behind changing it - perhaps this one's a bit more distinct between "read" and "new" states?

Comment: *“What does this have to do with achievements?”* – Rep are *not* achievements. And the bar chart [actually makes sense](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/149076/gilles?tab=reputation&sort=graph).

Comment: @poke But the title of the rep/bar chart box *says* achievements, and it also displays badges there.

Comment: @poke The hover text says “reputation changes” but the title when you click on it says “achievements”.

Comment: @Shog9 Floppy disks are used to represent save today because they were used to represent save yesterday. I've never seen that gray thingy to represent incoming messages before.

Comment: You’re right… it really does say “achievements”. Meh, it shouldn’t do that :/

Comment: I was comparing the envelope to the floppy disk, @Gilles - IMHO, the [letter tray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_trays) is a less familiar anachronism.

Comment: @Shog9 I see envelopes if not every day then at least several times a week. Letter trays, I'm sure I've seen one in my life, but they aren't exactly common, and I don't remember seeing one as an icon. Also, is the inbox icon supposed to represent a letter tray? If so, it needs work: it isn't recognizable even if you know what it's supposed to be, unlike typical floppy disk icons (you can always tell that they're 3½" floppies and not 5¼" or 8" — they're that recognizable).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/207461#comment660236_207420 (OT: they also make good pie racks)

Comment: There's hover text for the rightmost icon, but not for the inbox icon.  Surely I'm not the only that hovers over unknown icons before I click them?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I tend to presume that there's no button on SE that's both unclearly labelled and will cause irreversible damage if I click it, but the hovering thing isn't an unwise precaution regardless :)

Comment: @Gilles I'm seeing the letter tray more and more online. Confluence uses it for their notifications too.

Comment: @MatthewGreen Oh, is that what it is? Apologies to Shog9 then: I have seen a letter tray icon. I just didn't recognize it as anything but a non-memorable abstract shape.

Comment: For some reason, the messages and achievement icons were completely intuitive to me. Although I'm not sure about the usage of the word "achievement". Maybe just leave it as reputation - badges can count as "reputation".

Comment: We have bumped the contrast up a bit. On the issue of hit box size, I'm sympathetic but only with respect to tablet use cases. We will keep this on the discussion list.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell Only for tablets? What pointing device do you use on PCs that doesn't make it easier to click on larger areas? I want one!

Comment: @Gilles I don't dispute that larger areas are easier to click; I just think there is a limit where things just start to look weird.  Taking a quick look around, we appear to allow more horizontal spacing than Facebook and about the same as Google plus.

Comment: The achievements icon looks like a pipe organ to me.

Comment: I thought the Inbox icon looked like 3D goggles or perhaps a crop-top or sports bra.

Comment: @Amicable It looks a bit square for a bra, but I kinda want that to be its official name now.

Comment: When there's a notice for the inbox, the bottom of the icon looks ugly as you see part of the tray on each side. Should probably remove the tray when there's the red square over it, wouldn't look unprofessional.

Answer (score 47):

I miss the mouseover from the portrait that shows recent reputation activity. I know there is a dropdown that shows all of the reputation activity for the whole exchange, but it requires a click to open, and is a small area to target with my mouse.

Please bring back the mouseover popup that showed recent reputation when I hover over my portrait.

If at all possible, it would also be nice to see my user name again. I feel a little **too** anonymous.

So in that spirit, I would like to see my user name show up (user names in general) in this fashion

[image: travisj username]

And hopefully with this user's support (he had the longest name I know of)

[image: travisj username]

Please restore our names, everyone will be waffle endebted

---

edit

After using a script to show my user name next to the gravatar I can understand how both can seem to be clutter. Which would you rather have, a username or a gravatar? I am unsure, but I seem to prefer the username. Here is what that version looks like:

[image: username only]

Comment: +1 for user name, don't miss the reputation on mouseover that much. :)

Comment: The new achievements popup is a direct replacement for the old user one, so we're not really bringing it back as it was. You should instead suggest the specific things that you used in the old popup that you would like added to the new one.

Comment: @DavidFullerton - In retrospect, I think the main thing I enjoyed was the large area to target with my mouse, and that the area was centered to the screen. The convenience was hovering to open it. The new reputation breakdown is really quite nice in comparison.

Comment: However, I miss my name the most. **`var d = $("<div>");
d.css({display:"inline-block",verticalAlign:"top",paddingTop:"10px",color:"#aaa"});
var p = $(".profile-me:first");
var t = p[0].children[0].title;
d.html(t);
p.prepend(d);`** ahh, brings back memories...

Comment: Touch screen users dislike the hover since we can't hover...

Comment: +1 for mouseover to see recent reputation activity. Clicking on the name brought up your profile page before too, so no improvement there.

Comment: I say leave the username out, it keeps the bar uncluttered and clean looking. But then again, I use the site enough that I have an image specific to me that isn't auto-generated. Maybe newer users would be confused not knowing what the image actually is.

Comment: [Forks Undo's script to bring the name back](https://github.com/Gabro/SE-Topbar-MainMeta)

Comment: @GabrielePetronella - [forked](https://github.com/travisjj/SE-Topbar-MainMeta/tree/master) .. The light side. [Preview Image - SFW](http://i.imgur.com/NsQB3ZR.png)

Comment: I like the light style! Two concerns: the foreground color is probably only suitable for [meta]; I kinda liked the avatar next to my name, as in [this preview](http://cl.ly/image/271y3o1p0i18)

Comment: @GabrielePetronella - I updated the script to show both now.

Comment: A major advantage of the username is that you can use it as a target for [quick find](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/search-contents-current-page-text-or-links), I find that more convenient than memorizing shortcut keys.

Answer (score 42):

### Add the 10k suggested-edits-pending indicator back in!

I just noticed that 10kers don't get the nice little pending suggested edit indicator anymore... can we have it back?

Some mockups, in order of what I think looks best first:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, totally agree! Was just about to ask if it's removed and if so to put it back. Maybe it can become even smarter e.g. showing other queues as well, each with a different color, but that's a different story.

Answer (score 40):

I like the new style, but I'm wondering whether the *Hot Questions* tab is gone for good.

I happened to like losing hours of my time wondering through interesting questions over the SE network!

[image]

Comment: [Wait for a week...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/207503#comment660202_207420)

Comment: @hims056, thanks I totally missed it through the myriads of comments!

Comment: @hims056 but that sounds like it's only going to get hot questions from one site. Or is it going to pull from the entire network? That's the part that I like, learning about new things that aren't necessarily in my brain box.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar it will be the same hot questions from the entire network

Comment: @David then +1 full steam ahead!

Comment: @David CC on [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/207503#comment660848_207420).  Thanks.

Comment: @MonicaCellio You've got a legitimate use case, but it's just really low-frequency. In aggregate, our users just don't use the recent badge list. In all honesty, it's probably going to disappear, but I'm committed to making sure that it comes back somewhere. We are throwing around ideas for the /users page

Comment: @JeremyTunnell, I just care that it be available.  It doesn't have to be on the front page in particular.  I'm not sure how you're measuring (non-)usage, but it is something that mods and "senior" users on at least some sites use for community-building purposes, so I hope you'll be able to find a place for it.  Thanks for considering the request.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell can I ask whether you guys considered to put tabs in the new dropdown? *Hot Questions* could be a second tab next to *Explore our sites* and this would solve the issue of rearranging the side bar.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell [What about here?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cycz.png) (as for the badgers... I have [a script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/181456) running)

Comment: These are now live in the sidebar of each site's home page.

Answer (score 40):

It seemed odd to me that in the (awesome) new site switcher dropdown, you have to aim quite precisely to hit the correct link.

[image]

- On the **left**, the icon & name link to the actual site (http://pets.stackexchange.com).
- On the **right**, the reputation links to my profile.

As you can see, the pets element had it's hover state enabled while I took the above screenshot and the area marked by the [freehand red circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/172936) is just dead space.

> **Could we please make the entire element clickable?**

I don't mind having the reputation link to my profile (that's quite useful), but the rest of the element should be clickable as hinted to by the background's hover effect.

Comment: We will be making the hit box as large as possible, just didn't make this build...styling is tricky on that one.

Comment: This is done - all other dialogs also have this treatment.

Answer (score 28):

The Site Switcher [was fixed to show our sites correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207445/152515) - and that's great! Apparently it shows our top 5 sites by rep, plus the 'Main' for the site we're currently on.

However, it could be improved: **The sites at the top of the Site Switcher should be the sites we use *most often*.**

The sites I have high rep on are *not necessarily* the ones I'm using frequently. For instance, Board & Card Games is at position #8 on [my sites sorted by rep](https://stackexchange.com/users/93089/jonathan-hobbs?tab=accounts). On UX, I have only 103 rep. They're being crowded out of the Site Switcher by Programmers, Arqade and Code Review - I might have a lot of rep in those sites, but I haven't used those in *over a year or two*, so there's no value in having a quick link to them.

Rather than listing the top 5 sites we have by rep, it should do one of the following:

- List our top X sites, sorted by how frequently we've visited them. (For me, this would show: Meta, RPG, B&CG and UX. Wonderful!)
- Let us pin and unpin sites from the longer list that we actually want quick links to. (I would pin the above)

Comment: What about "sorted by last visit"? Would that be too dynamic?

Comment: @JanDvorak That would definitely leave the list jumbling around a lot. Something more steady would be better.

Comment: I can't find the comment, but giving the users the power to modify sort order is in the pipeline.

Comment: We're later on going to allow you to edit the order of sites (and which you see) there, exactly how the Android app does it now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195933/ability-to-alter-my-favorite-sites-in-the-android-app

Comment: @Kasra Wonderful! Thank you! :)

Comment: Maybe a bug: it does not actually show my top 5 sites by rep. For whatever reason, area51 isn't there for me (despite being my #2 site). I guess it's not worth fixing if this manual sorting thing is going to replace the autosort soon.

Answer (score 24):

Can you **PLEASE** put the chat link back on top?

I always go to it to get to chat easily.

Now it is an **extra** click to get to chat which seems like too much.

[Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198822/155556)

Comment: Try getting used to the site switcher. After playing with it internally for a few weeks, I think it's much easier to have all the site switching links in one place.

Comment: Hope you don't mind me copying your template! ;)

Comment: Haha nice one @ShaWizDowArd ^_^

Comment: Must be pretty hard to press that mouse button.  Maybe you need a new one.

Comment: Ehhh. But I like mine... :-(

Comment: @DavidFullerton It may be easier for devs who monitor many different sites. But 95% of my SE experience is via Physics Main, Physics Meta, and Physics Chat. Surely I'm not the only one who spends a majority of my time in one particular corner of the SE Network.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I didn't use the "chat" link much, but the "main" link (mentioned above) I could reach by typing "main", which autosearched for the text, hitting escape (to leave the link highlighted), and hitting enter (to follow the link).  Now I can't get to chat or main by doing that.  As much as I like the ThinkPad's trackpoint, it can be much easier to follow a predictably named link by _typing_ rather than hitting "Home" (to get to the top of the screen), moving a hand to the mouse, pointing, missing, pointing again, etc.

Comment: @RobertHarvey This doesn't apply to all the stack exchange sites, but StackOverflow is intended for professional and enthusiast programmers;  I think that that target audience is probably one of the most keyboard-centric that will be found, and it probably make sense to cater to them (at least on SO and Meta).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: So you're saying, provide a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sort of, except that in web browsers, textual links are _already_ pretty functional keyboard shortcuts.  Grumpy programmer want typey, not clicky. :) In all seriousness, though, I don't know of many websites that use keyboard shortcuts all that effectively (GMail comes to mind as one that does).  Unless there will be plenty of keyboard shortcuts, I don't know that the odd one here and there will be all that helpful.

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/KeenIIDX/SE-Topbar-MainMeta/raw/master/script.user.js) a userscript that adds the 'main' and 'chat' links.

Comment: @DavidFullerton I'm with ChrisWhite on this one; I spend more like 98% of my time on SciFi.SE, switching between its main/meta/chat, only occasionally venturing out to the other sites.  At the very least, _please_ keep that trio directly in the topbar as well as the menu...

Answer (score 23):

Could we have a colour scheme that doesn't burn my eyes?

Pretty much anything that isn't black (or just off black)

*(Edit to add by Benjol, my answer with this got [deleted as a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207517))*

> I could get used to the blackness here on meta, but I don't like the
>   StackExchange in colour: and I can't help thinking it's going to clash
>   on other sites.
>
> And applying it across all sites? What about [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), where
>   the top bar is part of the design? Surely you're not going to
>   sacrifice that on the altar of uniformity? And on [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) -
>   where it's already black, but nice and sleek and thin, not chunky and
>   imposing like the new one.

Comment: I like the black. I like the blue. Together? Not so much. Maybe the blue wouldn't burn quite so much if it wasn't the absolutely only thing on the page with that color.

Comment: What burns your eyes soothes someone else's. And Vice magazine versa. Also, like what colour?

Comment: @random Something that doesn't divide the page into BAR and NOT BAR quite so heavily. The light grey colour scheme felt like it respected the rest of the page, was an addition to it. This hits you in the face, saying "I am the most important,  don't look at the questions, they are not ME"

Comment: I think the real problem here is the light-colored rest of the page. Just think how great this is gonna look on [scifi.se]!

Comment: @Shog9 True, are the rest of the site's design going to change to compensate as well?

Comment: Not unless you request it and garner a ridiculously massive amount of support. I, for one, would really dig a light-on-black MSO... (but I doubt that too many others would)

Comment: @Shog9 It'll probably be much worse on Android/TeX/MiYodeya, etc...

Comment: Can we change the bar background from `#212121` to `#313131`? That seems like a small change, but it already makes a huge difference to me.

Comment: @Shog9 Maybe using some sort of secondary color on a per-site basis for the coloring? Either that, or finding a more moderate color which fits them all?

Comment: @random We need a color picker for it. Metro FTW!

Comment: [Here's a very simple theme](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xTj6V.png) that I feel doesn't cause much pain.  Although I don't know what one would do with the different sites and their unique top banners.

Answer (score 21):

There used to be direct link to https://stackexchange.com/ when opening the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™:

> [image]

Now I can't find direct link anywhere.

Can this please be added somewhere?

One option using the current design as-is is make the "Explore our sites" link to https://stackexchange.com/sites:

> [image]

Comment: The first one isn't implemented yet. But if we click on site switching icon (i.e. Stack Exchange) *while the page is loading*, it will redirect to http://stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @hims056 that's a "noscript" fallback, meant for those with JavaScript disabled (the raw HTML source simply has the link and JS code replace it with the awesomeness). Not really acceptable workaround. :-/

Comment: Ohh.. I didn't know that thing. :)

Comment: Blasphemy! There's only one name for it and it's SuperCollider. Just like god intended.

Comment: @Adnan Multi, not Super, unless you can prove otherwise? :-D

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Oh [there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120313) are [millions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115432) of us. **We** are the right ones! Unlike you, the followers of the false name. We shall rise!

Comment: @Adnan sorry but [MultiCollider](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22MultiCollider%22) bringd back 146 results while [SuperCollider](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22SuperCollider%22) only 30 results. **I win**!

Comment: +1 for "Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™"! I agree, though. I often used that link, and I want it back.

Comment: How about a variation:  making "our sites" clickable, in the first line of drop-down text:  "Explore **our sites**".  (Personally, however, instead of the link to the Stack Exchange [home page](http://stackexchange.com/), I'd prefer a link to that [WONDERFUL right-brained variable-block-size representation of the sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) :)

Comment: @Doug_Ivison thought about that too, it would be fair compensation. :)

Comment: This is done in the next build.

Answer (score 19):

Is there any chance of making the Inbox/ Achievements models wider? It all looks quite cramped for me @ 375px, with so much more width available on the page. Many items flow onto multiple lines.

Below, for example, shows it @ 500 px.

> [image]

Comment: See also [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207479/193139) about changing the height.

Comment: Wow, that looks a *lot* better. An alternative would be to clip the length of the titles rather than wrapping them (this was the behavior in the old rep drop-down).

Comment: @Shog9: Or a combination of both... wider *and* clipping lengths for those extra-long titles?

Answer (score 15):

As [I wrote before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199634), I find the number of votes I've cast today to be useful information, and I want to access it quickly as this is quickly-changing data. It was available before when hovering on the user name. Please restore it.

The number of favorites change would be good to have too. Where are favorite changes gone? I neither want them nor see them in the inbox, where they'd be clutter. I neither see them nor see them in the achievement list, where they'd be drowned in the mass.

On the other hand, the list of badges changes very slowly. It doesn't belong in the top bar, really. Removing that would be a nice way to make room for more useful information.

Comment: Missed your answer, thanks!

Comment: Gee, I miss the shortcut to Favorites **a lot**. Now, we are two clicks/screens away from it.

Answer (score 15):

**Feature-Request** to the "Recent reputation & achievements" button in the topbar beta.

The reputation changes are awesome e.g. +25, +4, etc. with the corresponding question/answer post. But, for the badges there seems to be no such thing. The following pic will make this clear.

[image]

Notice the highlighted "You've earned the Civic Duty badge." line, we could show the badge colour of this achievement before it.

I would like to propose the showing of the corresponding badge colour in the left column (where the reputation changes +25, +4, etc go) for the respective badge earned.

Comment: We've considered this, but there are a few problems with that: it's a lot of icons, and the badge icons are not consistent one site to the next, so we'd have to either a) pick a new and different badge icon (very confusing if it's not like your most used site at all), or b) load the CSS and sprite files for every site (crazy complicated and expensive).

Comment: You may try filling colours? If not, the new topbar is still fantastic!

Comment: @NickCraver How about one sprite file for the network with one row per SE site, and columns of bronze/silver/gold badges? Even if there were 50 sites it'd only be about 15-20kb. Whenever a new site leaves beta, just add a row to the sprite. If in future you want a new element shared between sites, just add a column for it. etc etc

Comment: @user568458 the badges are different sizes is the issue there, the top bar is supposed to be consistent.  The sprite for all SE sites is planned, as both a performance booster to favicon loads and lets us do retina versions *way* easier.

Answer (score 13):

I find the font used for the text, especially the numbers, is too difficult to see. Can it be thicker/bolder/have more contrast?

Comment: Light grey on white shows you how hip the site is

Comment: If you're talking about the inbox item text, I just pushed a fix for it. Before we had an opacity of 0.8 on "read items," dark text for new items. now all the text are the same dark text. We'll be adding a new visual treatment for "unread items" later

Comment: No, I'm talking about the font used for reputation points and badge counts, for instance.

Comment: @jin You know what it needs?  Some bold.

Comment: Bolding the rep points (or something else to make them stand out - maybe just bump the font size slightly?) seems like a good idea. The other tweaks that were made seem to have sorted out the readability issues, at least for my eyes and monitor :-)

Answer (score 13):

Could we have reputation sums next to more items in the achievement list?

Currently, only today's reputation is summed. At the very least, yesterday's sum would be interesting to know:

[image: sum of all fears]

Comment: Today is only summed if there's only 1 site with rep today (since a single site icon + total is a huge space waster and adds no value).  It was not the intent to sum all sections.

Comment: What OS and browser were used to take this screenshot? The top bar of the menu is going out more than the rest of the dropdown, similar to what I have under Ubuntu and what is also showing in OSX.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Windows 7, Firefox 25.

Comment: @NickCraver It wasn't until you posted that comment that I realised it was showing reputation gains across all sites :-)

Comment: I like this idea, but we can't do it for technical reasons.

Answer (score 13):

**I want to know about votes on my answers/questions *after* reaching the rep-cap.**

The achievements dropdown is simply fantastic. I really like the idea that you can see you rep changes network-wide. There has always been something that irritated me even with the old top bar; you cannot know about votes on your answers after hitting the rep-cap. You see, it's very nice, you hover over the old one and it used to tell you what answers got upvoted. But after hitting the rep-cap, you're left in the dark.

Probably something along the lines of:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I have a weird display error with the network drop down in Firefox. The width of both the header and the actual content box is bigger than the wrapper around which restricts the size and also makes the drop shadow. The header is actually even wider making it look very weird:

[image: Before and after]

On the left you can see the box how it is currently displayed for me. The gray header is actually wider than the rest of the box. If you look at the drop shodow at the bottom, you can also see that the scroll bars are actually partially outside of the box. The screenshots are both cropped at the same position, so you can see the difference in width.

Removing the `width: 100%;` from both `.topbar-dialog .header` and `.topbar-dialog .modal-content` fixes this.

---

It looks like they missed the `-moz-` prefix for `box-sizing: border-box;`, that's why it looks good in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

```
.topbar-dialog .header {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Important bit */
    padding: 10px 10px 4px 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.topbar-dialog .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Important bit */
    padding: 10px 7px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: It's not just Nightly - [this is occurring in Firefox 24 as well](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ipb2D.png)

Comment: Happening on Firefox 25.0 as well

Comment: Slightly embarrassed to say I didn't notice this when I opened it up originally, but I can confirm (again) on FF25.

Comment: They just forgot to add the `-moz-` prefix for `box-sizing: border-box;` that's why it looks OK in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Comment: Even on Firefox 25.0.1

Comment: Sorry this one fell off the radar, a fix will go out in the next build.

Answer (score 10):

The box in Firefox on OS X is broken. Somehow it doesn't like that padding there.

[image: Broken Box]

(Newest Firefox, OS X 10.9 (Mavericks).)

Comment: It's not an OSX bug, but a firefox one - we'll be sure to give Firefox from love today. I guess it's obvious now that we develop mostly on Chrome :)

Comment: Windows Firefox (Win 7, Firefox 25.0) doesn't seem to have these problems

Comment: @NickCraver So, it is a firefox bug, especially created for OS X it seems :-D

Comment: Not only OSX, under Ubuntu 13.10 with gnome 3.9.90, I got a similar bug, the top of the dropdown is going way out.

Comment: A fix for this is rolling out in a bit.

Comment: @NickCraver nice, looks fine :-)

Answer (score 9):

The achievements dropdown is really confused a lot of the time when leaving a Meta page open.

The achievement box doesn't reload the drop-down after further achievements are gained. If you leave a page open, gained reputation, and opened the drop-down once, the *next* time you gain reputation the green rep counter shows your gained points, but clicking on the dropdown then shows old, now stale information.

Here I gained an accept:

[image: ah, rep gain!]

but the dropdown shows old, stale info; I am at +260 by now really:

[image: but, wait, I already had +230 today]

After closing the dropdown, the green label disappears, but after opening a new page, the count is back and opening the dropdown gives:

[image: hey, I am at +260 really]

adding in the most recent two events (one of which I had not yet seen).

Note that the achievements counter didn't clear properly either. I opened a new page (or I could have reloaded the current page), and the same green reputation gained count showed up *again*, creating more confusion.

Can the achievement handling be updated to continue to work properly when one page (a questions list) remains open for a prolonged period of time? After gaining more reputation, the dropdown contents should be reloaded and the server updated that I have seen the reputation gain properly.

The same problem largely applies to the inbox as well. The unread messages number doesn't stick like the green reputation delta does, but the dropdown is not reloaded on new messages. This is rather irritating, having to open a new page just to read the message and have a click target. This was reported [in a separate Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208116/the-inbox-in-the-new-top-bar-isnt-refreshing-properly) as well.

I've also seen it report the total reputation gained for the day so far, intermittently, showing a +230 after I had already opened the dropdown. I'm putting that down to a temporary glitch for now.

Comment: Is this the same as the [bug I noticed with the inbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208116/the-inbox-in-the-new-top-bar-isnt-refreshing-properly)? I haven't opened my achievements box since the first day, so I didn't check that.

Comment: @Gilles: Could be, I've seen some inbox weirdness as well. I'll keep a close eye on that.

Comment: achievements [have been intended](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/207687#comment661436_207687 "per comments of SE developer") to be _much_ more understandable than garbage that is currently shown to you: "The big green number is how much rep you've gained since the last time you checked."

Comment: @Gilles: the inbox is working fine for me at the moment. Both your comment and gnat's showed up separately and the count cleared properly both times. Opening a new page doesn't show the inbox counter again.

Comment: @gnat: Yup, which is why I am reporting it here.

Comment: @Gilles: Okay, I have to take that back. This applies to the inbox as well; the number updates properly but the dropdown itself does **not** reload. I am looking at a stale inbox with the new message not listed.

Comment: We now cache and de-cache this appropriately, it was waiting on a rather large JS refactor.

Answer (score 9):

I'm just wondering how this will fit into Ask Ubuntu, they already have a top bar that needs to match up with a specific aesthetic.

[image]
Adding the all-new almost all-black top bar would seem *wrong* somehow. At the top it would interfere with the Ubuntu top bar and it would be equally bad (if not worse) where the old bar is right now considering it's black.

Comment: Heh, me too...I had to make that damn thing pixel perfect with the other Ubuntu properties :)

Answer (score 8):

I really like this - although it will take some getting used to. Two feature request though, one related to [one I asked some time ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98412/154443):

- Can the order of sites in the drop down **please** be user configurable, perhaps with options for sort by rep, most recent visit, alphabetical or possibly drag to sort?
- And can we set how many sites we want before it goes to the general view. Most days I look at my top 12 sites, but also another couple that are of extra interest but that I still have low rep on. I'd like to have them all easily and quickly available through the drop down.

Comment: The order of sites will be user configurable yes, not at first release but it will be.  I'm not sure what the limit will be on this.

Answer (score 8):

When registering on a new site and you receive the 100 reputation bonus, the 100 will be added in the reputation box, but no information on where or why you got the reputation is added to the list.

Comment: This item is now in the list, along with several others.  We provide the site icon, text, and a link to the help article explaining why you got the bonus.

Answer (score 8):

I keep clicking this text thinking it's going to bring me to the [all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) page.

[image]

IMO, it's intuitive that it should. And I'd like it if it did, because I've grown accustomed to accessing certain sites by navigating first to the all sites page (if only because that page is pretty :-).

In any case though, can we *at least* add the CSS property `cursor: default` on it so the cursor doesn't change whilst hovering past that text? 95% of the time we toggle that dropdown, we're gonna have to cross that text to click on any of the links. No one will ever need to highlight that text.

Comment: I agree, that would be a great place for the all sites link.

Comment: This will be a link in the next build.

Answer (score 7):

When hovering over a site in the "Explore our sites" list, why not display the site links "chat", "blog", "meta"?

> [image: SE top bar: site links when hovering]

It wouldn’t "hurt" in any way. Everyone hovering over these site links either wants to visit the SE’s main site or wants to visit a sub-site (meta, chat, blog) of it, by clicking at the main site first, and then opening the StackExchange menu again and clicking at the sub-site link. So it would save 3 clicks and a site load.

A different solution would be to display a little icon (e.g., a triangle) right from the site name, which, when clicked at, opens a little menu with the sub-site links (similar to [Google’s Cache link](https://superuser.com/a/669835/151741)).

Comment: Duplicate of http://me... oh, wait. We can't close answers.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Pardon me? Duplicate of what?

Comment: @unor Congratulations, you have successfully duplicated an entire person

Comment: I don't really want hovers everywhere. Tooltips are fine, but I think this might be a step too far.

Comment: We also plan on making the site hit box as large as possible, that wouldn't yield some counter-intuitive behavior and introduce trouble clicking.

Answer (score 6):

Can we have a little clicky drag thing (my brain isn't working tonight, I can't remember what they're called) to drag and change the height of the inbox? It's a minor thing, but I don't like that it goes so far down the page. This is my personal preference, so rather than changing it for everyone, it would be nice if we could drag to adjust the height ourselves (not the width, obviously, but the height.) And if it would remember what we'd done previously, that would be great :)  Obviously this isn't a hugely important request.... My eyes can travel a bit further down the page if they must :)  But it seems odd to me for a header element to go so far down the page, so it'd be a nice-to-have for me to be able to adjust the height to my own preference.

Comment: You mean something to resize the window?

Comment: @JoshC Yes. What are those things called?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the technical term is "grippy resizing thingamajigs".

Comment: See also [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207558/193139) about changing the width.

Comment: @Shog9 [yummy](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUua3.jpg)! ;)

Answer (score 6):

The 'activity' link seems to be gone. I use it quite often to keep track of posts I've voted, commented or answered on. Now I need to go to my profile first and then click on the tab.

Perhaps a menu in the style of 'Inbox' and 'Achievements' could be added?

Comment: Yes please! I use that link too. I could just visit my profile and click the activity tab, though - but I'll upvote this since I'm a regular user of the existing link.

Comment: This is my most used link as I use comments as a way of keeping track of what questions I might need to revisit... losing this means _soo_ many more clicks.

Comment: I think inbox is proper place to add an "activity" link.

Answer (score 6):

Some more feedback concerning reputation.

1. <s>**Can [I haz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Can_Has_Cheezburger%3F) my Stack Overflow rep?**</s>

   I believe this is a bug, and I think somebody else noted this already, but it's probably worth stressing it: the Stack Overflow rep is missing in the dropdown.

   This has been fixed.
2. **Can I haz my Meta rep?**

   The dropdown is a nice place where I can see all the reputation points across multiple sites. I know it's probably redundant, but I would like to also see the reputation points of the site I'm in. Currently the meta reputations points are not being displayed and the chat/blog/logout links have been moved there.

   I know I can see the reputations point a few pixels away on the top right, but I still think having all the reps listed together would be nice.
3. **You broke my workflow!**

   I used to click on my reputation point score to jump to the *Reputation* tab in my profile. Now I have to click on it (1) and then select the reputation tab (2). I know most of the information is now in the reputation dropdown, but hey, I still think the reputation tab is useful (bar charts!)

   Two clicks, can you believe it?! I suggest you to cause a CPU overheat when I hold my spacebar so that I can configure it as shortcut to the reputation bar chart.

[image]
Image by xkcd: http://xkcd.com/1172/

Comment: Number one is a small oversight, and we will fix it. For number two, I'm afraid there just isn't anywhere to put it... and it's literally an inch and a half to the right. On point 3, the new  achievements drop-down should contain about 80 or 90% of the information you used to go to the rep tab to look for.  It's just not a top-level use case anymore.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell thanks for the reply. On point 3, couldn't be feasible to differentiate between clicking on the avatar and clicking on the score/badges? Pretty much as clicking on the site name takes to the site homepage and clicking on the score takes to the profile (by the way, this really should take to the rep tab)

Comment: We could do that, but even if we did, I'm just not sure the reputation page would be the page we would send people to. What are you finding on the reputation tab that you don't find in the achievements drop-down,  and how often does that happen?

Comment: @JeremyTunnell the reputation tab is site-specific, so by clicking on my rep I can quickly see all the rep changes for the site I am in (as well as visualizing them by post, time or graph). The rep dropdown is lovely, but I still want to focus on a specific site and do it quickly. Adding a link on the reputation score sounds trivial to implement, it would be coherent with the current behavior and I don't see any evident downside.

Comment: I also just noticed that if I click on the logo in the reputation dropdown it brings me to the reputation tab. Two comments: 1) it's still two clicks away; 2) the link is not there if my reputation didn't change today

Answer (score 6):

The "logout" functionality has been effectively hidden.  It is now only under the "StackExchange" drop down menu.

[image: logout in stackexchange drop down]

I would expect "logout" to be associated with my profile.  If the logout link is not available in the nav bar, the first thing I try is looking at my profile.  If I navigate to my user profile, the logout functionality is not apparent.   The "My Logins" link there looks promising, but doesn't offer any functionally for signing out.

A drop down called "StackExchange" is pretty far down my list of places I would try to look for a logout link.

While I like many of the features of the new bar, the logout needs to be more prominent.  I would suggest adding a "logout" link on your own user profile.

[image: add logout to profile]

Comment: could this be related? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207902/205473

Comment: Very related.  Even so, I disagree with the premise from the other post that it needs to be fewer clicks from a stress injury point of view.  I'm trying to emphasize that users  need to be able to figure out how to perform the action.

Comment: It's like hitting the start button to shutdown. Sounds familiar?

Answer (score 6):

The notification for new message looks odd when you look at it. Everytime I have that red square, I get the feeling something isn't right with it. It was until I actually took time to think about it that I understood that the odd look came from the tray behind it and it wasn't the red square that had a drawing problem. I zoomed the image for a better view but the normal sized appearance looks like the square isn't right. I still find the look bad even knowing this.

The red notification square for a new message should either be bigger as to overlap completely the tray or the tray behind it should be removed. Either option will make it look better IMO.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

My two cents:

- The contrast between the blue Stack Exchange logo and the black bare is terrible. Consider making either the Stack Exchange logo or the bar’s background light grey (preferably both, like it was before).
- The amount of whitespace between the badge counts and the help button is way too large.
- The icons next to the Stack Exchange button are not sharp but rather fuzzy.
- Where did the chat button go?
- Where did the current user drop down button go?

If this would be the final bar, I’d be sure to add this to my user style sheet:

```
.topbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Or you know, just make it possible through a user setting to bring the old bar back, which was totally fine anyway.

Comment: I do agree that the colour scheme is horrible. But the chat button is within the site changer now (chat isn't used ever day for most users so it seams reasonable to take it off the top). There are improvements as well however. I like the rep change notifications

Comment: @rightfold - I made a light version of the bar ([preview](http://i.imgur.com/WHaB4DN.png)). The code for it is [here](https://github.com/travisjj/SE-Topbar-MainMeta).

Answer (score 4):

Should there really be a green icon for each rep change? It's distracting and I keep clicking it :P

Then again, that might just be because it's new, I'll probably learn to ignore it.

What happens when there is an acheivement of another kind, like the edit/badge notifications? Edit notifications are more important than the rest, I don't want to end up ignoring these too. Will there be a separate icon for these?

Also, what happens to mod messages/replies now? Are they buried under the notification bar?

I understand that there's going to be a third dropdown, but I guess that will only be on the sites where I have a diamond. Will mod message notifications only be accessible from the site I moderate?

Comment: That's a really good point about the mod toolbar. One could argue that you technically only need it while on your sites, but at the same time... It'll be strange to have access to all your notifications on some sites, and not on others.

Comment: Edits should now appear in your inbox (we didn't want you to lose/skip over them, either). A mod message that's a direct reply to you will be in your inbox (you'll be notified on any site, like any other inbox message). Copies of messages other mods send will be in a new dropdown that you only see on the site(s) you moderate.

Comment: If it's going to be a separate dropdown, it should be visible on every site for every user that has mod abilities on any site

Comment: @JanDvorak We talked for a long time on this, and went with an approach that allows mods to be regular users on other sites. Just because you're a mod doesn't mean you should be constantly pestered by modthings on sites you *don't* moderate (which is why we don't show you flag counts everywhere). The most *urgent* of mod notifications would be a direct reply to a mod message you wrote, which is why we're putting those in the inbox. (cont'd)

Comment: Flag count, copies of other mod messages, etc. are important but not urgent. We trust that moderators regularly check in on the sites they moderate, so we thought it would be too aggressive to show those things on any site.

Comment: @Laura +1 for the edits. I understand about the mod messages (I was debating whether or not to keep that bit in the post myself), it might only really be applicable to multi-mods who may not always visit all sites. But the messages usually aren't that urgent anyway.

Comment: @Manishearth We're going to roll it out the way I described above, but don't be shy (not that I think you would be) about letting us know if it turns out to be horrible in practice. We're aiming for maintaining sanity while staying on top of moderation duties; some adjustment may be required to achieve that balance. :)

Comment: @Laura Poor ChrisF just might go insane switching back and forth to check the mod dropdown ;)

Answer (score 4):

I keep thinking my gravatar is a notification. I suppose I'll get used to it eventually, but the reasons I think this are:

1. The gravatar is small; looks to be about the same size as the inbox and rep icons.
2. The gravatar flashes in and out when it loads, but everything else on the bar doesn't.

So it's the size of a shiny notification, and it flashes in and gets your attention. This is what the red "you have mail!" inbox notifier on the old bar did; it faded in after the rest of the bar had loaded. So the gravatar keeps tricking me into thinking something has changed, when really it hasn't.  Any way to make the gravatar load at the same time as everything else? Obviously the size won't change, but if it were static I don't think I'd think it was a notification (I don't think the inbox and rep icons are notifications, after all.)

Answer (score 4):

**The Achievements dropdown should more clearly explain where the numbers come from.**

**Including the +1's from Community Wiki votes** because it just becomes weird when those are involved.

I had +51 show up when I visited the site just now, with no explanation as to why it says +51 in particular. +50 would be understandable, but where's the +1 come from?

[image: an unexplained +51 reputation]

I *think* it's from a Community Wiki upvote. So I might have received 50 rep from 5 upvotes, then [my suggestion in this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207470/152515) became community wiki and received one more upvote.

It would be helpful to see a breakdown for this. Something like:

- +30 *The new top bar is out on meta. Consider it a beta*
- +20 *A question of some kind*
- +1 CW vote on *The new top bar is out on meta. Consider it a beta*

Comment: I didn't get any CW upvotes today yet saw inconsistent totals as well. I suspect there are some issues to iron out still. Like loading the popup over AJAX again when the you received some more votes. Or not showing the '+score' badge on the icon after reloading.

Comment: What OS and browser were used to take this screenshot? The top bar of the menu is going out more than the rest of the dropdown, similar to what I have under Ubuntu and what is also showing in OSX.

Comment: @JonahtanDrapeau Firefox Aurora. [It's been reported for various versions of Firefox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207473/152515).

Answer (score 4):

This is possibly by design, not related to the changes, a different change I've missed or something that MSO is just an exception for, but moderator new meta questions don't show up in the inbox:

[image: Biology meta notifications showing up on Gaming Inbox]
*Biology meta notifications showing up on Gaming Inbox*

[image: No notification on meta stack overflow]
*But no Meta love*

Comment: There's a separate diamond inbox on sites where you have one where this will go to.

Comment: So we wont get notified on other sites once this rolls out?

Comment: @Rory Yeah. Not sure how I feel about that, tbh... The inbox is SE-global. If I'm browsing SO and I get a ping on ELU, I'm immediately notified. So I feel like I should be able to have the same thing happen for moderator notifications... Just because I happen to be on another site doesn't mean I don't want to know if something has happened on the sites I moderate. I think the idea behind this was to let us relax and be normal users on other sites, but in practice I think it might make me feel like I have to switch back and forth between sites more often. Let's give it a fair chance (cont'd)

Comment: and I'm sure if we all end up not liking it SE will be open to hearing our thoughts and possibly modifying it :)

Comment: Here's a possibility: If you are a mod _anywhere_, the top bar has a diamond inbox. It contains items for sites you're a moderator on, and keeps you notified of mod stuff happening on one of those sites from anywhere else in the network.

Answer (score 4):

The inbox-icon looks like a printer-icon. It should look more like an idealized open letter.

Comment: I believe it is supposed to look like, well, an inbox. I.e. on of those things on your desk that irritating people put things in for you to deal with

Answer (score 4):

For a minute I thought you had decided that using Stack Overflow would now require and be integrated with a G+ account.

Comment: That would make me rage filled (I have developed an irrational hatred for G+ for no reason that I can identify)

Comment: The day is quickly coming that "Google Account" and "G+ Account" are the same thing.

Comment: @BenCollins if I'm honest that is quite a lot of my reason for the irrational hatred.  I used to be able to leave reviews on android apps just fine but apparently I need a G+ account now: so I don't leave reviews any more

Comment: @RichardTingle sorry.  You might think about finding a way to cope, because when the two account systems are unified you won't be able to get *apps*, either.

Comment: As long as it doesn't fill Stack Overflow with ASCII tanks, I don't really mind Google+ integration

Answer (score 3):

It might be just me (I don't see anyone else having mentioned this), but when I click on the Stack Exchange dropdown and see at the top of the list "Meta Stack Overflow ... chat / blog / log out", that looks to me like those three links only affect *that* site. Which is even more confusing because I'm not even terribly active on MSO!

I'd say that **the links that don't relate directly to any one site should go together with "explore our sites",** *not* together with any one particular site. That makes it much more clear that they are network-wide.

[image]

Comment: But, those thinks *are* specific to that site. Each site can have its own blog, and each site has its own little sector of the chat system that lists room specific to that site. For example, the "blog" link on Programmers SE goes to [this URL](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/).

Comment: @animuson In that case it is definitely non-obvious in my opinion how you'd chat on SuperUser. :) (Being a regular on SE I probably could figure it out, but someone not quite so vested in the network might not.) And surely "log out" isn't site-specific?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling The chat link behavior actually hasn't changed, even though the location of the link has. Chat used to be a top-level link in the top bar, but it only went to the chat for the site you were currently on. In the new site switcher dropdown, it behaves the same way: link to the chat room(s) for the site you're on. It's pretty rare that you'd want to get to a chat room for a site you weren't currently on, but we haven't made it any harder to do so. (Although we didn't make it easier, either.)

Comment: @Michael: As far as I know, log out *is* site-specific. When I want to log out of the Stack Exchange network, I go to every site I logged into individually and log out of each.

Comment: @icktoofay Maybe my problem is that I don't log out of Stack Exchange often enough to really know. :) If it is as the comments claim, then I guess this whole answer becomes moot. Sorry for taking up peoples' time with trivialities :)

Answer (score 3):

I would like to see the achievements tab 'remember' what sections I collapsed and what sections I want to be open between two page loads. It currently only remembers this until I click a link to an other page

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a bug with the top bar and Internet Explorer 9 (don't question it, they forced me!). When there is a number on top of the achievements button and the user clicks on it, sometimes the browser tab will completely crash. I think it might be related to clicking outside the achievements window to close it. It happened twice to me today, but I am not sure if it is related to just this computer or to all IE9 browsers.

Comment: We have refactored the JavaScript completely, are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: First time I will be able to test it is in 1,5 week.

Answer (score 3):

I do not like its blackness. It's hard to see dark grey on black and it's very contrasting with the white bg.

- Will there be an option to change the color of the bar?
- Will there be an option to hide it?

Answer (score 3):

"The Workplace" has disappeared from my list of sites in this version. Is it because it is in beta? Can we have a list of our beta sites too if this is the case please?

Edit: It is there if I search for it, but not in my list of sites I have an account on. Strange:

[image]

Comment: did you scroll down far enough? As far as I see, sites where I've got no rep points (besides association bonus) are displayed in alphabetic order, which would put Workplace far far down. My Workplace account has more than that, so it is listed closer to top for me

Comment: @gnat Added an image of the dropdown for me. I only have the association bonus on The Workplace, but that is the same for some other sites there so I'm a little confused.

Comment: at your screen shot, scroller is at the top - drag it down, to the bottom of the list

Comment: @gnat Underneath the ones I have listed there is then just the search box and all the other sites in the entire list that I do not have rep for. You can see the top of the search box in my image, that is the end of the section where my sites are displayed. I have 101 rep on The Workplace, just as I do at Server Fault so would expect it to be in the top list

Answer (score 3):

Overall, not bad. Some specific criticism:

- The solid “almost” black is too harsh a contrast with the white page background, and gray-on-black will just about disappear under less-than-optimal viewing conditions (glare, bad monitor, bad eyes, bad gamma — take your pick). I would prefer colors which match the site theme.
- "Achievements"? We don't have no stinkin' *achievements* around here. I guessed this was supposed to be a term for “reputation and badges” (if so, it's a bad choice, because "achievements" has a specific understood meaning which reputation does not fit), but I don't see badges I've recently earned listed there (or anywhere else).
- I think moving chat and meta links into the site switcher is not the best idea, for a specific reason: chat and meta for a given site are not different sites, they are *ways I can further participate in this site*, and having them be prominently linked has helped **me** choose to participate more in those ways.

Comment: What would your definition of achievements be?

Comment: @RichardTingle SE badges are achievements under a different name. They are generally specific, named, one-time awards for specific accomplishments.

Answer (score 3):

The actual gravatar image should be twice as big to look nice in HDPI screens.

At the moment the size of the image is 24px and the requested size is 24, but instead it should be 48px for the same size.

Here is the difference and it's quite noticeable on HDPI screens when it's not optimised for them. I think also that is not worth it to treat it differently in that case and requesting for 24px size for normal screens but rather requesting always the 2x size.

[image]

Comment: Disagree with always requesting a 48px one. Resizing an image to a smaller size in the browser usually looks horrible.

Comment: @Stijn that was an issue back in '90s.. today they are doing quite a good job.. so it's an extra work for not that important issue.. but the point here is that we need the 2x for the HDPI screens for sure.. how it will handle the smaller ones is another issue..

Answer (score 3):

I LOVE it.  The only thing I miss is seeing my name, for some reason.  It's almost like a little security blanket I didn't even notice.  Sure, the avatar is great, but there is something subconscious missing.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207955/178816

Answer (score 2):

I was slightly shocked initially (I even cleared my cache thinking that something had become corrupted and showed the background as black).

It's OK I guess, I didn't really have a problem with the old one though. The missing "main" and "chat" links are a loss to easy navigation.

Also, in my opinion, I don't really like the vibe of the solid black bar. I feel like I'm on some silly blog site (or in one of Google's zillion different themes on their sites). The old bar felt cozier and integrated.

Answer (score 2):

Two points.

**Resize Achievements Window to Fit Content**

It looks really peculiar to have a large white space left when collapsing the achievements window. It should be relatively straight forward to have the expand/contract to fit the content with a little Javascript.

Alternatively we could draw a cute little ghost in the unused space.

**Collapse Categories by Default**

I would collapse "Last 30 Days" and "Older" by default. As I think the majority of users will only be interested in their recent reputation changes / awarded achievements, when not viewing from the reputation page on their profile.

[image]

Comment: We have a very long tail user base, so where you may get changes every day, others may only get 1 a week or so.  The interface needs to work for both those scenarios.  The dropdowns are also all a constant height by-design.  I agree it looks odd when totally collapsed, but not sure what we'll do there.

Answer (score 2):

You now need three clicks to log out - click the Stack Exchange name & logo, then the "log out" on it's menu, then the final log out button.

Previously it only took two clicks - hover on username, click the "log out" link, then click the final log out button.

As ICT professionals we are vulnerable to RSI, so IMO basic functions like logging out should require as few clicks as necessary.

Ideally, I'd like a "log out" button on the top bar itself.

As an alternative, maybe hovering on the Stack Exchange name & logo could cause it's menu to appear automatically. Just like hovering on your name in the old design automatically gave you the dropdown with the logout button.

Comment: The "R" in "RSI" stands for "repetitive".  Just how frequently are you logging in and out? :-)

Comment: HOLY CRAP YOU LOG IN/OUT A LOT. Not kidding. Wow. You win a prize or something. Is RSI a prize?

Comment: Physically figuring out *how* to log out seems to be quite a challenge in itself (without your OpenID logging you back in anyway)

Comment: I find the placement of the Log Out link for the current site quite odd considering that most sites put it next to the user name link or in a drop down that is opened when you click the user name. Having it in the site list is not very intuitive. I suppose if the goal is to eventually have a Log Out link for each site that you're logged into so you can log out of several sites from one spot, then yes, keep it there, but for God's sake, please put one in a more logical place for the more common use case.

Comment: @Shog9 maybe a badge for this? :-D

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd What, a Sarcastic Comment badge? :-P

Comment: @S.L.Barth no, badge for logging in and out A LOT. ;-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd On a serious note, I see his and Monica's Cellio's point. Still, I have had times when I had many SE sites open at the same time, and going to three clicks each to log out is inconvenient IMO.

Comment: @S.L.Barth question is, *why* you log out so much? Of course it's your full right, but most people (myself included) just never log out.

Answer (score 2):

I like the achievements feature, but I think the icon could be improved.

[image: Achievements icon]

I can see now that it is supposed to be some sort of graph, but it looks, at first glance, more like Mum, Dad and their three kids are out walking in the dark.

Which isn't exactly suggestive of what functionality it supports.

Could you please make the icon less suggestive of a group of people?

Comment: You have some odd thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Mod-messages are not shown properly. The picture below is **not censored**.

[image: mod messages]

Comment: Maybe related to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209878/152859)? See Nick answer about "non-post items", if the message is about user and not a post it might be the same bug. :)

Comment: Fortunately, these are: http://i.stack.imgur.com/s1uAN.png

Comment: Deploying a fix for this in just a bit.

Comment: ty, any chance to get a more useful line than "MOD added a new message"? maybe containing the title of the used message template, too, and the recipient's name?

Comment: Should be fixed now; the mod inbox now uses the same template as the network inbox.  As for more informative mod messages, this is planned, but some refactoring needs to occur before this can happen.

Answer (score 1):

Can we have the reputation abbreviated with the usual *k* units, please?

[image]

wout turn into the much more readable:

[image]

Comment: I don't see reason for abbreviating the reps there, but I definitely would like to se a thousands separator.

Comment: Well, it's abbreviated *everywhere* except for the profile and the former top bar, so I don't see why it should take that much space here. Either way is fine though, but without separators it's unreadable.

Comment: Well if you want an overview of your reputation across multiple sites, I kinda like not having it abbreviated. Separators needed indeed, but I suspect they'll be there in the final version.

Comment: Hrmph! We finally found a place to show rep where the possibility of overflow is nil, and he wants _abbreviations_. Sheesh, people, _make up your minds!_

Comment: Except when you have over 100k rep on Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair Stack Exchange. In all seriousness though, if you want to show the full numbers then please use decimal separators, @Tim.

Comment: Abbreviations are good :)

Comment: Separators are good, but I'd like to see the full numbers there.  I shouldn't have to go all the way to my network profile for that info.

Comment: The rep numbers now have their missing commas - we don't intend to abbreviate them, there's plenty of room.

Answer (score 1):

Consider running a test for achievements indicator, assuming a user who starts with something like +20 (+50, +100...) and then gets frequent +1/-1 rep changes from answers un/downvotes.

To me, it took quite a while to figure that flashing green digits indicate "daily reputation balance across the whole network" which lights on every time I get tiny rep changes from un/downvotes or when someone removes an answer I downvoted once upon the time.

It gets even more confusing when these flashes start messing with larger "daily total" updates from upvotes / accepts. Frankly, I am not sure how long it will take me to get used to this...

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6s08.png]

---

Per my reading of [comments from SE developer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/207687#comment661436_207687), it was intended to behave differently, showing only increments compared to last time I checked:

> **The big green number is how much rep you've gained since the last time you checked.**

Comment: FWIW, it is change since you last opened the "Achievements" bar, not "daily reputatation balance". I think it takes getting used to as an old member, but for new members it's pretty intuitive; especially when clicking the "+21" shows *exactly* where that +21 has come from.

Comment: It was like that in the old design as well, can't see anything wrong with that. Actually, I do like to see when a post I downvoted gets deleted in real time. And for the record, it's only rising, downvotes won't affect it. :)

Comment: @Matt nope, I tested - it shows "daily rep balance" or something like that to me. And it lits up with that value every time I get +1/-1 of answers at Programmers or TWP - I'll update screen shot to show that

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd "it's only rising" doesn't match my observations - per my recollection it was getting lower. As for "the old design", I just tested it at main site - worth noting it was contained only to updates at current site - it didn't leak stuff from all the network, and wasn't intrusive (I saw it only when I clicked, it wasn't blinking into my eyes)

Comment: @gnat: Might be a bug in that case; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207687/163863 (inc. the comments).

Comment: @Matt per my observations, calculated "daily network total" was accurate - I found no errors in numbers shown to me, only that these numbers felt weird, even after I figured their meaning

Comment: @gnat: It's not the intended behaviour though :P (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/207687#comment661436_207687)

Answer (score 1):

Where can I easily see the server time? I want this when I have hit the rep cap, used all my votes, or otherwise been busy. Time zone math was never my thing and there's daylight savings too, so I always used the reminder at the bottom of the rep change dropdown. Where is it now?

Comment: It's now at the top of the achievements drop-down

Comment: So it is! I didn't see that, thanks!

Comment: @JeremyTunnell: it's great to see it back, but that seems a bit of a strange place for it - what does it have to do with achieving anything? It'd be better placed on the MultiCollider (or maybe the inbox drop-down), IMHO.

Comment: It's for checking on rep caps, mostly.  And that was where it was on the old drop-down

Answer (score 0):

The badge notification includes the text "see your profile" but the whole thing is just a link to the question or answer that earned the badge. There is also no colour indicator for those who haven't memorized whether Great Answer is gold or silver.

I tried to get a screenshot but failed. Hovering over the words "your profile" shows a link to the question or answer but it should be to your profile.

Here's the old notification:

[image]

Each of the bolded words is a separate link.

Comment: When you earn a badge on SO main and you click on the notification in the inbox, it takes you to the post where you earned the badge. It also does not indicate the class of badge. The only place you see the class of the badge is when you hover over your username to get the summary - and that feature was removed.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what a good answer badge looks like in the new dropdown: http://i.imgur.com/9MfCr2d.png (it links to the answer)

Comment: @TravisJ I can get a screenshot like that. What I wanted was one with the cursor (showing) over "your profile" but the link still being to the question. This is not how it was before and still is on main.

Comment: Already reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209151/152859)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd thanks, added a comment there

Answer (score -1):

Previously we had 2 possibilities to check our daily reputation sum:

- Hover over the name on the top bar
- Click on the rep to get to the reputation tab of my profile

But now both possibilities are gone.

Could we split the link to the profile again to take me to the rep tab when I click on the left side or directly on the rep number?

[image: Profile link]

Comment: Open achievements. You can see there today's total earned reputation by sites. You can also redirect from it. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198678/187824

Comment: You're right. Did not see that until I got rep today.

Comment: I have to admit that today's total earned reputation by sites will appear only if we have earned reputation on more than one site for today. May be we can ask them to show total earned rep even if we earned rep on single site.

Answer (score -1):

Could we please get the [AJAX bug fixed that doesn't update the rep display](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209648/13295)?  Currently, any rep increase will update it, but rep decreases only show when you refresh the page in some way.

[image: Reputation Updater]

Comment: This is by design. Negative changes don't update automatically.

Comment: @Emracool, yes, I know it's by design, and I'm asking them to change it.

Answer (score -3):

What does everyone think of badge notifications going into the main inbox instead? How intrusive that would be would depend on how often you get badges, I suppose, but my current fear is that the badge notifications are going to be lost in all the content that will be in the graph dropdown. I definitely want to know when I get a badge, but all the other info that's currently on that tab I just check from my user profile. I'm not going to probably use that tab, and I don't want to have to sift through it to find badges because there will be so much other activity...  Does that make any sense? /ramblings

(There's always the option of letting us customize where we want certain things...  "Do you want badge notifications? Inbox/Rep Tab/No" etc. But that's probably more work than needs to be added right now.)

Comment: Ugh, please, no. I have a hard enough time keeping up with my replies. I'm already a bit worried about edit notifications being mixed in. Keep the badges out in the brownie point bin.

Comment: Currently there's a nice separation between;  things you should probably read and things you can ignore if you want. I say keep it as it is

Answer (score -3):

Please add the name of the current site to the bar.  I would suggest that it be added at the front of the bar, but it could also make sense after the StackExchange dropdown.

[image]

This is because moving to a meta site or a chat site is such a jarring experience.

I'm embarrassed to admit how long it took me to realize that the "meta" link changed to "main" in the current incarnation of the bar as a way to get back to the main site.  For months I was hitting the back button 10 times or going to my bookmarks to get back to the main site.    The same is true for chat for me.  The logo for the main site is placed and sized differently enough that it took me a long time to figure out that it was clickable.

The Stack Exchange drop down is a vast improvement over the current implementation in this.  At least you have to click in the same place to back out of meta as you did to get into it.  But it doesn't seem to go quite far enough.

Having a consistent clickable logo icon for the site (main, meta, and chat) would make navigating within that site much smoother.

Comment: Three down votes and no comments?

Comment: I think people are taking this as being a bit more "electiony" that a normal Q&A, but I was against this because (a) it looks kindof horrible and (b) it repeats information that is perhaps a centimetre below it

Comment: On the main site it would repeat the information, but not on meta and chat, which is where I would find that information most useful.  As for looks, its just a mockup, I'm not a designer.

Comment: Ah, I thought your meta vs main in your mockup was a mistake, I consider them to be seperate sites. So the functionality you want back is the [main link back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207423/220332). I'm on the fence with putting "main/meta" back in but having 3 different site names (Meta Stack Overflow, Stack Overflow and Stack exchange) next to each other like that isn't a plesent solution

Comment: I almost want the "main" link back.  Certainly from meta that is part of the intention.  I really want meta and chat to be considered part of the main site and an easy and consistent way to get "home" to the main site from whatever part if it you are in.  I have hated the "main" link in the current bar.  It took me forever to realize it was even there.

Comment: I think thats the thing though, the designers don't consider main/meta/chat/careers to be the same site. They consider them seperate sibling sites

Answer (score -4):

Is there any reason for the empty space between the badges and review, and between help and the search bar?

[image: ??]

I don't think the space is needed, specially since the rest is closely packed.

Notifications, inbox, and Stack Exchange button have a gap of just approximately four pixels between them.

Comment: They're seperate groupings on two levels (ThingsOnLeft || ThingsOnRight(Achievements||Links||Search))

Comment: I find it a bit much - I don't actually think it's that bad an idea to reduce it slightly.

Answer (score -8):

Add a shadow to avoid going from white to black in 0 pixels difference:

[image]

Comment: Does it need a shadow? Is there anything wrong with it going from (almost but technically not) black to white immediately? (our text does that, our buttons do that on either side, the Questions / etc links at the top go from dark grey to white immediately, etc)

Comment: it needs it more than it doesn't, just the bar, I am not a fan of dropping shadows everywhere. I wouldn't even add shadows to the current buttons (but someone did, and you don't hear me complaining about it)

Comment: But _why?_ For what reason should there be a shadow?

Comment: hard to tell, but not harder than to tell why there shouldn't be one

Comment: There shouldn't be one because it's unnecessary and unnecessary visual elements add clutter and noise to a layout. The same reason the top bar doesn't have much else in the way of stylistic elements. Necessary, useful visual elements are good, but they're only useful if there's a point to them existing.

Comment: sorry, what can be asserted without reasoning can be dismissed without reasoning.

Answer (score -10):

Since this is a new roll-out top bar... I would love if this bar survives scroll. Something like [Google+](https://plus.google.com/) does.

> [image]

The main advantage here is I can access my new top bar even when I look at the last question.

Comment: No no no no no no!

Comment: It's hard to put into words but these always make me feel detached from the website,  like I'm not in full control (also; they always seem to go wrong and have a second of flicker on old system, although im sure the competent people at stack exchange could avoid that)

Comment: @RichardTingle I like sticky toolbars. If the official one settles to being static, I will probably add a userstyle

Comment: This is an old request: [Should the top navigation be frozen?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101385) (see also the linked questions). And the answer's NO.

Comment: you can write your own user script in few lines to achieve that

Comment: If you were to make a userscript for this, it could even have a "dock/"undock" toggle so that it would either stick or not.

Comment: For example (top right dot is the toggle): `$('.topbar').css({zIndex:10,position:"relative",top:0,left:0});
var ol = $("<div>");
ol.css({position:"fixed",zIndex:5,top:"10px",width:"7px",height:"7px",borderRadius:"5px",right:"2px",cursor:"pointer",paddingRight:"2.5px",backgroundColor:"black"});
$("body").append(ol);
var pos = false;
ol.click(function(){
 pos = !pos;
 var t = $(this);
 if( pos ){
  $('.topbar').css("position","fixed");
  t.css({zIndex:15,backgroundColor:"#fff"});
 }else{
  $('.topbar').css("position","relative");
  t.css({zIndex:5,backgroundColor:"#000"});
 }
});`