# Why is my StackOverflow with an indent and doesn't have reputation

Tags: discussion

Well everything is in the title.
Why is StackOverflow showing up with a indent and why don't I see my rep next to it like on the other websites.

> [image]

Comment: Please add as an answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207420/155556

Comment: I don't think that's necessary. More than one person has already remarked on this in that pile of answers.