# What is the next step in the closing process?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

Let me explain.

This: [What is the purpose of indenting "StackOverflow" under "Meta Stack Overflow" in the new Top-Bar's Stack Exchange selector?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207597/what-is-the-purpose-of-indenting-stackoverflow-under-meta-stack-overflow-in)

Is a duplicate of this: [Why is my StackOverflow with an indent and doesn't have reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207449/why-is-my-stackoverflow-with-and-indent-and-doesnt-have-reputation)

Which is also a duplicate of this: [The new top bar is out on meta. Consider it a beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207420)

I can vote to close a question but not close it myself with a single vote (obviously).

So what if I spot a question that is an **obvious** duplicate but it isn't noticed? I am the only one voting and, with time, users lose interest in that question as it goes down in the question feed.

What is my next step here? Leave it like this? It will stay a duplicate of a question that was already a duplicate. It doesn't make much sense.

Is there another step in the process?

There should be a way to tag a question to say *like hey guys please take a look at this question*.

Like a flag, but for a user with closing rights because right now **it is not showing up in the review queue**.

> [image: review queue screen shot]

Comment: Things take a while to show up in the queue. At least 15 minutes

Comment: @Richard is right in that aspect. The close vote (or flag to close) has to have existed for at least 15 minutes before it becomes eligible for review. At that point, it will be added to review the next time the script runs to fill the queue.

Comment: -1 for a circle that is both not red and clearly not freehand.

Comment: @Servy Sorry for the delay. It was fixed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*You* don't see it in the close vote queue because you've acted on that item.  It is not something that *you* can review.  The review counts are based on the items available for *you* to review.  Everyone who loads the page doesn't see the same number.

*I* see that item in the close vote queue:

> [image: Close review count]

---

> [image: Question in close queue]

Comment: Should have thought of that... Thanks Servy