# Let me use the arrow keys when searching in the site switcher

Tags: feature-request, top-bar, stack-exchange-button, accessibility

When I want to switch to a site that's not in my top five by rep, I enter a term into the search box in the site switcher menu:

[image]

And there it is -- that's the one I want! Let's go! My hands are already at the keyboard! I can't wait! ***Arrow down***!

<sadtrombone>

[image]

(Nothing happened.)

Can you please let us move out of the text box and through the search list with the arrow keys, the same way tag completions work? That would be swell!

(I'm on Mac OS X.)

Comment: Related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207526/cannot-navigate-into-the-multicollider-with-keyboard-so-cannot-access-main-m

Comment: Did someone vote for duplication? I'm seeing the "This question may already have an answer" banner, but no close vote. That's confusing.

Comment: @JoshCaswell i flagged it, but currently i´m unsure if it was correct. So i need to let the mods decide

Comment: Thanks, @SnowballChristmasLight. That's interesting; I didn't know the banner appeared for a flag.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of the one I posted as related (hence why I just said it was just related) but there is definitely some crossover there. There are probably dozens of keyboard-navigation questions that would all be related but still separate individual issues.

Comment: @JoshCaswell with the new close system, a close **flag** is treated exactly like a close vote in every way except no vote is recorded.  If you vote to close a question with a flag to close, you'll even see the flag reason lumped in with the oter close reasons in the close dialog

Comment: Good to know, @psubsee2003; thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate to the next result and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate to the previous result.

Comment: uhh.. the down key is _still_ more intuitive than tabbing

Comment: That's only working for me in Chrome, not Firefox or my usual browser.

Comment: @JoshCaswell For me it works in Chrome 31 and FireFox 26

Comment: @JoshCaswell what _is_ your usual browser?

Comment: @JanDvorak: It's unsupported, so I'm never sure it's worth mentioning it (although it is using the same WebKit engine as supported Safari). Anyways: OmniWeb.

Comment: That should have been linkified to lead here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OmniWeb :-)