# What is the purpose of indenting "StackOverflow" under "Meta Stack Overflow" in the new Top-Bar's Stack Exchange selector?

Tags: discussion, top-bar

In this screenshot:

[image]

I see:
1. The current site I am on
2. My top 5 sites
3. A search bar to locate other sites.

All of this is really good - but I'm not sure I fully understand the impact of the "Stack Overflow" indented under Meta Stack Overflow.

Obviously, the relationship between a meta and main site is logical - but how is this intended to operate when looking at a non-meta site?  Will the order still exist and simply be reversed, will it be empty, or is there a set of business rules to define what will be there?

Comment: One would assume that on SO the MSO link would be indented, to show the link between the site and it's meta.  The site you're on is at the top, the meta/main counterpart to that site is below it, indented for emphasis, and the top 5 are below that.

Comment: Of course meta isn't SO's meta, its the parent meta of them all. Which makes this questionable

Comment: Presumably to also show `Meta` indented on Stack Overflow when on the main site. Let's ignore the part where Meta is special for a moment.

Comment: there would better be a "connecting arrow" there, to explicitly indicate reference meta->main `└──>`

Comment: @RichardTingle maybe it means that [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange) is coming sooner than 6-8 weeks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the new location and format of the meta / main switcher. When live on Stack Overflow, it'll flip up and look like this:

[image: Indentation Reversed!]

You can find more information about why the meta/main links are being moved into this format and location here: [The new top bar is out on meta. Consider it a beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta)

Comment: Are we to assume that (based on this image) rep will still not be shown between main/meta on sites where it's not shared? On the [beta thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta?answertab=votes#comment660309_207451) it was mentioned as "probably a bug", but this image makes me wonder.

Comment: If it's marked as a bug, then it's a bug.

Comment: Previous click count to get to Meta: 1. Future click count to get to Meta: 2. Fail :(

Comment: Complain on the linked thread, please. @gserg