# Duplicate entry in new top bar for Meta SO

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Very minor bug. We've all seen [The new top bar is out on meta. Consider it a beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207420/147362).

I've happened to notice a duplicate, redundant entry in the Achievements dropdown, when I achieved a Yearlings badge on a sister site:

[image]

Comment: Ouch! Two badges, one for the meta site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You earned the Yearling badge on two different sites.  (As can be seen from the different logos.)  The two notifications is appropriate.

Presumably you created your account on those two sites on the same day.

Comment: One notification is for Server Fault and the other is for *Meta* Server Fault (note the grey out icon).

Comment: @AnnaLear but except here on the main Meta, on every Stack Exchange site account is automatically created for its Meta site as well and the Meta reputation is the same meaning this badge is **always** given twice. This does look bit... redundant.