# Add Data Explorer to the new top-bar

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, top-bar

[The new top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta) does not contain the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) in the list.

Can we please add it?

<sub>Area51 is in the list too. So don't you give me a *This is no real site* argument.</sub>

Comment: But Area51 nets you reputation, the Data Explorer doesn't. So it's not a real site, really! :-P

Comment: Neither does the old top bar, unless I'm missing it?

Comment: It's not part of the official Stack Exchange network. It's a third party site, using the contents of Stack Exchange database (mirrored an filtered) with permission. We have link in the footer which is enough IMO. :)

Comment: More importantly, I already have problems with some of the more complex queries at peak usage... don't want more people to find out about it!