# Main meta layout issue

Tags: bug, meta, design

I noticed today that the "StackExchange" dropdown on the top left of the main meta site, when open doesn't lay out correctly - see the image below:

[image]

The right column (reputation, etc) is shifted outside the div.  This is Firefox 24 on OS X Mountain Lion.

Comment: Duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207530/172011

Comment: @juergend Yep, looks like one - strange, it didn't show up in the suggested questions when I was posting this one.