# The inbox in the new top bar isn't refreshing properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox, top-bar

It seems that the inbox on MSO still isn't refreshing properly. I believe the initial pains are supposed to be fixed, but it's difficult to see in the huge [feedback thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta), so I'm reporting this separately.

I had a tab open on MSO and another tab open on another SE site. Someone commented on one of my posts, and I saw a notification appear (red ①) in the inbox on both sites. I decided to open the MSO inbox, probably less than a minute after the notification appeared. When I clicked, the list of replies did not include the one that triggered the notification: the latest reply in the inbox as it appeared on MSO was my [then next-to-last reply](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/23313?noredirect=1) dating from a couple of hours ago. When I opened the inbox on the other SE site, I saw my [latest reply](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/155240?noredirect=1) as I should have. After refreshing the MSO tab, the inbox showed my latest reply.

This doesn't happen all the time: I've also observed the inbox to refresh properly. So far, my observations are consistent with the following:
With the new top bar, **if I've already viewed my inbox in a tab**, then when a new notification comes in, the red ① is displayed as expected, but **the list of messages displayed by the inbox is not updated**.

Google Chrome 30.0.1599.114 if it matters.

[The same bug has been observed with the achievements list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/208183#208183).

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7.

Comment: @gparyani I can reproduce (still in Chrome): I had an MSO tab open, and my inbox in that tab isn't showing your comment. This isn't systematic. I suspect that this only happens if I've already accessed the inbox in that tab.

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to Chrome 31?

Comment: @gparyani Chrome 31 is out? Oh, it came out last week. I think my Chrome process has been running for longer than that. I'm not an upgrade freak, I'm content with software that's more than a week old… Why should I waste time upgrading all the time? I wish there was a stable version of Chrome and Firefox!

Comment: I noticed this too several times, but wasn't able to reproduce. Hopefully they're still working on the whole thing and fix that before it's spread across the network.

Comment: I saw this happen earlier as well. There was nothing there, but when I clicked it, the notification showed and then immediately disappeared. I was using Chrome Version 31.0.1650.57 m

Comment: As for Chrome, just close it once a day and make sure to tick "Continue where I left off" in the settings - next time you open it you won't lose anything and get auto updates this way.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd “Close it once a day”??? Why on earth would I do that? I do have Chrome configured to save tabs, but that doesn't save everything (scroll positions, window placement, everyting incognito, …). Also I don't use auto updates, no software gets the privilege to break behind my back. I use the Ubuntu packages and run `apt-get upgrade` when I feel like it.

Comment: @Gilles can't judge you, but Chrome is fast to update, and sometimes they're doing breaking changes. Anyway on this specific issue it doesn't matter, it's most likely server side issue. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Breaking changes are a reason not to update.

Comment: I certainly see this with Chrome 31 on Mac. Leave a page open, load the inbox when a message comes in. Any **new** messages after that won't show in the dropdown as it is not reloaded for new messages. The same applies to the [achievements dropdown and green rep delta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208183/140890), only worse as the rep delta doesn't reset properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed before the top bar rolled out as part of a large refactor of how the whole thing worked client-side.  Apologies on the delay updating all the questions related to topbar bugs, trying to clean up now.