# Total reputation for today in new topBar is missing

Tags: discussion, support, top-bar

In Achievements dropdown, the total reputations was shown near ["today" till yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207575/233367)(if I remember correctly). Even if you collapse Tday, it used to show.

[image]

Is this feature removed?

EDIT:
I guess this happened because today I got rep from 2 accounts and therefore the total rep is not calculated.

[image]

### Update:

Yesterday, I was not able provide this in a screenshot,

[image]

You can see the difference right?  Hope this is enough to prevent closing of this question?

Comment: Is this a timezone offset thing?

Comment: No, it never was like your first screenshot (you obviously made it yourself) and it was always shown only for "Today". Are you suggesting a feature request here? At its current state I have no idea what you report or ask here.

Comment: I think you just got confused: the screenshot comes from [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207575/152859) where the user is **asking for a new feature**. It does not exist yet.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Sorry, I thought it was there.  Will delete this question.

Comment: No harm done, just pay more attention to reading in the future. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thank you.  You used to clarify all my doubts whenever I post a question.  Thanks again :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a feature that was requested, not something actually implemented. 

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan doing my best, when online. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I have updated my question with screenshot, hope now this question is clear to be answered.

Comment: Sorry man, after long time I realized what you meant and the cause for this. I have submitted a [feature request now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211634/152859) asking to change this behavior.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Atlast you got my point :) +1 Thanks for creating feature request.