# Show total reputation gained today and yesterday, even if on more than one site

Tags: feature-request, top-bar, achievements-dialog

Currently, when we gain daily reputation on one site only, the total is shown besides the label, like this:

> [image]

That's nice and dandy but if I get reputation on more than one site, there's no total whatsoever.

When expanded, it will show the reputation gained on each site:

> [image]

So it would be nice to see *+73* in such case next to "Today", with tooltop being possibly "You earned 73 reputation today on Stack Overflow, and Meta Stack Overflow". (yes, that's an [Oxford comma](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199098/152859) ;))

Comment: I'm afraid that's not an Oxford comma, old bean; you only need a comma when you have a list of more than two items, don't you know. Your comma is unnecessary.

Comment: @Josh oh, well, guess, I'll never, learn! :(