# I want more total reputation!

Tags: feature-request, reputation, top-bar

In the **old top-bar** we had the possibiliy to see daily, weekly and monthly reputation totals.

[image: Old topbar]

With the **new top-bar** only daily reputation totals are left.

[image: New topbar]

#### Can we please also have to weekly and monthly totals back?!

Comment: you mean [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207456/221351)

Comment: No, I don't want all of it back.

Comment: Phew - you're talking about the top bar. And here I was with a broom ready to clean up the ashes. I'm such a cynic.

Comment: @Tim I think many were with the finger ready on the downvote/nuke button from reading the title alone...

Comment: I just wanted to make the very feature-request. I guess I already did a few months ago...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting comment from [this answer/request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207456/152859): (Emphasis mine)

> [Kevin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/172958/kevin): I see now that there is rep-by-question in the... right-most left-hand box, but it would still be nice to get the day/week/month summary, maybe on top of that pulldown.
>
> [Jeremy Tunnell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/202998/jeremy-tunnell): We'd like to be able to do that, but the way we had to aggregate across sites **it's just not possible for us to get the day/week/month roll ups** with the performance we would need.

Bottom line it means we won't get those back any time soon because in the old top bar it was per-site reputation while in the new top bar it's from all sites.

Comment: Oh, I did not see that comment. It was hidden having no upvotes.

Comment: @juergend yeah, it's not very popular but guess we'll have to face reality. :)