# Bug in new rep counter in SO top bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, deleted-answers, top-bar

I noticed something odd with the top bar, but I blew it off as me seeing things (again), but low and behold I wasn't. After deleting, editing, and undeleting an answer I had been upvoted on, the counter seems to go a little nuts.

I had answered a question and gotten a few up votes on it, but I wasn't happy with my answer so I deleted it. At some point I clicked on the reputation change in the new top bar to clear it. I went back to edit my question later and then undeleted it. Of course the votes I had received were still there, and once the system recognized my undelete action, the new rep counter showed this:

[image]

I would have imagined that it would show the votes I had earned prior to deleting it (+40), or at best a total for all my points today (nowehere near 431), but that's what it showed.

Comment: Has happened with me too!

Answer (score 2):

I have finally found and fixed this issue, I posted the details [on another question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211537/135201).