# Deleting a post makes the rep count go crazy

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, top-bar, achievements-dialog

If you delete a question that was modifying your reputation count (+/-), close the site page and come back, you will have a nice surprise.

Your rep count will show you all the reputation points you made today.

> [image]
>
> [image]

<sub>That was the point of my test post btw.</sub>

### Reproduced again:

[image]

Comment: What was the value before deletion the question, 0?

Comment: @NickCraver Yup. Well... `- X` but since you don,t show negative rep I don't know exactly how much I had lost. Both time I reproduced it it was after rep loss. I posted a question where I asked someone to downvote me. Then I deleted the question I got this result (twice).

Comment: "Bug catcher" badge is yours! ;)

Comment: @NickCraver: I've also seen this behaviour when a question I answered was deleted shortly after I posted a CW answer.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Hope this one won't get closed as Off-Topic ;p

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd not just yet, has to be fixed first then it can be closed as no repro. (sadly, there are people who actually think this way including at least one mod, likely more)

Comment: @juergend Party breaker.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd well, you did the actual bug hunting job and got 25 reps (so far) - looks like fair game. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yeah. I love going on bug hunts on thursday. That should be a thing. But hunting thursdays where all user click everywhere and try to do wicked things to the front page.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd were you able to reproduce this consistently? having a hell of a time getting a repro here, but it's got a lot of moving pieces

Comment: @NickCraver Yes. Got a post up saying please downvote me. Deleted the post when I had 3-4 downvotes. Just after deleting I closed the browser to get a 5-6 minutes delay to make sure it's all gone. Repro that twice.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd can you reproduce again please?  We can't repro but it may be a delay issue we can't imagine with the aggregation queue that is very hard to repro locally.  I've just deployed a lot of logging around this so help us figure out where the glitch is.

Comment: I can yes but what will you learn if I reproduce ?

Comment: @NickCraver Repro again. (look a post update) also the post I made is this one : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211347/please-downvote-me-for-but-testing?noredirect=1#comment679178_211347

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd $#%@#D*AD)ADA bug in the logging and deploy - building again in a moment

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd can we try it one more time? logging confirmed working now.  No offense but I have a team of developers ready to downvote you...

Comment: @NickCraver - I keep seeing this behaviour. Generally when an answer I previously downvoted gets deleted.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd Thanks for your help in tracking this down, details are here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211537/135201