# Are total reputation points adjusted from time to time?

Tags: support, reputation

I’ve noticed that, from time to time, my total reputation points are changed, generally for small  amounts: 5, 10 or 20 points for instance.
The issue is not the adjustment itself but I wonder  how that comes about.
There is no evidence of these adjustments in  “reputation” or “votes” summaries such as “user was removed” and the like. Apparently no visible action was taken.

So my question is, are there reputation adjustments possibly made by the system, probably on old posts, that result only  in the change in the total reputation count  without any visible action to users?

Comment: If you visit [/reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/reputation) on any site you get  all your raw reputation events. There might be correction events there are not shown on your profile reputation tab.

Comment: @rene - interesting, and how can I access to that file? and what sort of adjustments are they, from counting errors?

Comment: If you clicked it, you just did. That is all the access there is. I named it *raw* for a reason ;)

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation for how to interpret that page.

Comment: @rene- I see, my question is, where can I get to that sort of file from my profile.

Comment: There isn't any. That /reputation route is the only thing, and it is unlinked so you have to type it yourself in the address bar.

Comment: Old [outdated answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7954/282094); apparently the recalc is done a few times per year in the background (low priority) but I can't find the comment / answer.

Answer (score 3):

As Nick Craver mentions in [this great answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211537/152859), the answer is "no", it's not being adjusted on its own:

> Here's what happens when your rep is recalculated (pretty much **this only happens when a post you possibly had any stake in is deleted or undeleted**)

So judging from this, reputation is recalculated only when a post is deleted (or undeleted), not on its own. Post might belong to someone else of course, e.g. question you answered or edited, but your rep might be affected as a result.

Comment: Thanks, so these rep adjustments are sort of “background noise” and for this reason they are not notified I guess.

Comment: @user121863 most likely answers that you have downvoted, and then they got deleted. Those won't leave a trace, as far as I can tell. This explain positive rep changes, as for negative, it's also for posts deleted that did not belong to you yet affects your rep, as mentioned in my answer.