# Did a mod remove a wiki that did not exist?

Tags: support, community-wiki

Today I noticed [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/207420/revisions). I saw this

[image]

Prior to that revision that the mod removed the wiki. I didn't see where the post was made community wiki.

Is there something I am missing? or Did a mod remove a wiki that did not exist?.

Comment: When a post turns into CW automatically there might be no indication for that.

Comment: @juergend How will the post have turned to CW automatically without 10 edits from the OP?

Comment: I think there is a threshold of answers that will push a question to CW

Comment: @Tijesunimi Edits from 5 different people, or 30? answers to the question.

Comment: It turns into CW when *The question generates more than 30 answers*

Comment: @juergend You are right; but doesn't the history show an automatic Wiki-fication from 30+ answers already?

Comment: @juergend But a mod removed the wiki before it was turned into CW by 30+ answers

Comment: @AndrewBarber: I could not find any.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta#comment660337_207420

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta#comment660505_207420

Comment: This [must have been fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/281328/revisions).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently, when a moderator removes the wiki status from a post, it removes all traces of the wiki ever existing and just leaves a "Mod Removes Wiki" notice in the history. If the wiki were to be removed from it *now*, the existing "Post Made Community Wiki" notice would also be removed. I've mentioned this to a developer in passing (when they were working on the new moderator timeline) and he simply said he wasn't sure how difficult it would be to get that original wiki info into the history.

So by seeing a "Mod Removes Wiki" event, you *can* imply that it was a community wiki at some point before that.

Comment: By the way, this appears to have been fixed.