# Suggested tag wiki edits don't show reputation gain in Achievements tab in new top bar?

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, top-bar

When suggesting tag wiki edits, their approval and subsequent 2 reputation don't get shown in the Achievements dropdown.

Got 18 reputation on Super User with 8 from tag edits, Achievements only shows 10 reputation.

## [image] <sup>→</sup> [image]

---

<sup>*Posted separately [from my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208931/222623) on the original 'new top bar' question per [comment by Sha Wiz Dow Ard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/208931#comment668535_208931)*</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), per [a comment by Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/208931#comment672583_208931) on the now-deleted [post (10k-only)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208931/222623).

> These now show up in the achievements dropdown. – Nick Craver♦ Dec 4 at 17:56

…and indeed they do…

[image]