# Double clicking stackoverflow logo highlights background on right

Tags: bug, status-declined

When I double click the stackoverflow logo the background on the rightside is highlighted. This is not reproduced on StackExchange! See the scrreenshot.
[image]

Comment: This isn't really a bug. This is typical, as double clicking something will highlight it. In this case, it's just highlighted oddly due to the positioning of the element.

Comment: Browsers’ll do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, **that's kinda what browsers do.** The default for who-knows-how-long has been to highlight whatever's under the mouse at the time upon double-click. <s>This isn't really something SE can 'fix', as it's a browser feature.</s>

Well, they *could* 'fix' it, but SE could also render everything in Flash, and get rid of the highlighting problem altogether. It's just not done.

Comment: Actually, they could prevent it, though they shouldn't. You can [prevent an element from being highlighted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Comment: Yes... but that ranks right up there with abusing HTML tables for layout. Or using Flash to render a webpage. So yes, they could but they shouldn't.

Comment: What's that have to do with tables/flash? It's just a CSS property.. `user-select: none;`.

Comment: @JoshC: Try it, then. Does it work as you expect? :]

Comment: In terms of usability and stuff :)

Comment: @minitech Yep, it effectively prevents the elements from being highlighted. Though you would have to be very selective, as applying it to the `body` element would disable all selection

Comment: Open up your f12 dev tool, and add the [CSS from this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting/4407335#4407335) to the `#header` element. It works. Additionally, if the new topbar is added to the main site, it wouldn't be needed anyways..

Comment: @JoshC: If you apply it to the body, it works and is annoying. If you apply it to the header and select all, even weirder parts get selected anyways – arguably the same sort of bug.

Comment: Just something worth noting. On this site it doesn't behave like SO

Comment: @AlexanderKimaru, here in Meta the [new top bar is in beta testing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207420), it will propagate to the other sites (shortly, I hope:)