# Top bar search doesn't pick up subdomains

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, stack-exchange-button

I wanted to switch to [our Cooking site](http://cooking.stackexchange.com) in the handy dandy site switcher in the new top bar. Entering "cook" brings up nothing:

[image: me want cookies]

... so I have to remember that the boutique title of the site is "Seasoned Advice":

[image: me want... seasoning?]

... in which case the site switcher also thinks that maybe I was thinking of heading over to [Travel](http://travel.stackexchange.com) to see what's up. So the site switcher searches site names and descriptions, but not subdomains. This is unexpected behavior - I believe it should search all three.

Comment: Confirmed, it only hits on boutique names and descriptions. Searching for Gaming, Judaism, Cooking, or Apple is odd, if you manage to hit a sub string in the description then you nail it, otherwise poof.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207442/) in the big messy feedback thread.

Comment: As Ilmari noted, this is part of the huge backlog of bugs on the original thread - presumably the devs will be sufficiently recovered by next week to wrap these up.

Comment: @Shog9 don't you think it's better to open separate reports for top bar bugs? Going through the posts on the announcement will be... cumbersome and bugs might just be lost.

Comment: After this thing gets rolled out network-wide, we'll do that (might still want a single point of entry for a little bit even then though). For now, having a single list with everything in it makes it *less* likely something important will get overlooked before the roll-out. @Sha

Comment: This is a bit tongue in cheek, but your own employees posting duplicates of something buried deep in that quagmire makes me skeptical of the truth of that statement, @Shog9. I'll agree to disagree on the chosen approach, though. :P

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a change since this bug report was created, but the search does pick up phrases in the site description.  So searching for "DIY" will return "Home Improvement" and "Apple" will return "Ask Different".  May be easily fixable by incorporating the URL Name in with the description in some fashion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is now fixed on meta as of revision 2014.1.12.1846 and will go out to all sites in the next build.