# Searching for maths in the new top bar does not return anything

Tags: support, stack-exchange-button

If I am looking for the maths section of the stack exchange network, I would expect it to come under a search for maths. However for some reason typing maths into the search box returns no results.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: It works for me. http://stackexchange.com/search?q=maths

Comment: @Gelatin in the top bar

Comment: Do you mean here? http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbo97.png

Comment: @Gelatin that's the one

Comment: why are we getting so many duplicates of this question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you are running into is frankly a localization issue, not in the programming sense, but just in general language sense.

"Maths" is not a word in US English (honestly, I cringe every time I see it typed, but I realize that it is common place in people who learned UK English).

The site is called Mathematics not Maths.SE and the search is incredibly unforgiving because it is looking for exact matches and <s>does not consider the URL nor</s> does not consider pluralization.  Hence, when you type "Maths", the search does not find a match.

This would impact any site in which you tried to find a plural form of the site name, so it is not unique to Math.SE.

<s>As [Mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215829/searching-for-maths-in-the-new-top-bar-does-not-return-anything#comment697784_215831) and [Kate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215829/searching-for-maths-in-the-new-top-bar-does-not-return-anything#comment697798_215831) point out in the comments, the site search under the Stack Exchange button in the new topbar is looking for exact matches with the site name and the description, not the site URL.  So searching for `gaming` or `cooking` will yield nothing, whereas searching for `Arqade` or `Seasoned Advice` will find the appropriate sites.  Searching for `DIY` or `Home Improvement` will return the Home Improvement site because DIY is in the description of the site.</s><sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> - this functionality was [just fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215842/182513) so searching by URL name is now supported

Comment: The search truly is unforgiving; it doesn't even search the site URLs. You can't find Arqade (gaming.stackexchange.com) by typing `'gaming'`; you have to type Arqade.

Comment: @MarkAmery I think this has persisted with the new topbar.  My memory isn't what it used to be, but I remember seeing a feature request in the past to address that (specifically with Gaming and Arqade).

Comment: It finds Home Improvement when I search diy... is that because it's in the description?

Comment: @KateGregory yeah, probably because of the description.  Cooking doesn't return anything, but Seasoned Advice does.

Comment: @KateGregory Yeah, it searches descriptions. E.g. typing `people who like` returns Board Games, while `Q&A` returns most of the network.

Comment: If it helps I cringe every time I hear people say "math". To be honest neither are real words and it should really be mathematics.SE

Comment: @RichardTingle technically the site name is "Mathematics".  It is just the URL that is math.

Comment: the searching description but not url is reported here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209396/top-bar-search-doesnt-pick-up-subdomains

Comment: @KateGregory yup, I opened my own [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215839/eekkkk-apparently-gaming-se-does-not-exist-aka-site-search-in-topbar-has-troub) before someone pointed me to that one, which is why it got reopened.

Comment: @MarkAmery apparently [this just got fixed on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215842/182513) and will be live everywhere in the next build.

Comment: I cringe every time I see maths misspelled as 'math' — it is incredibly weird to see mathematics abbreviated to math!