# Eekkkk! Apparently Gaming.SE does not exist (aka Site Search in topbar has trouble finding some sites)

Tags: feature-request, search, top-bar, stack-exchange-button

> NOTE: This issue was first brought up in [The new top bar is out on meta. Consider it a beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/207442#207442), but since that post is now locked, I want to initiate a proper feature request to update this functionality.

The site search built into the new top-bar is a great feature, but as discussed in [Searching for maths in the new top bar does not return anything](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215829/searching-for-maths-in-the-new-top-bar-does-not-return-anything), it is incredibly unforgiving.

In particular you run into problems trying to find some sites by the URL.

When using the search, the feature only looks in the site name and the subtitle/description for the site.  Where this becomes a problem is for sites that had graduated and have received their own name, and the URL no longer matches the site name.

For example, trying to find Gaming.SE:

[image]

If you know Gaming.SE existed, but did not know the name was "Arqade", you might run into problems.  "Gaming" yields no results.  If you searching for "game", you do find it because "videogamers" (sic) is part of the description, however, it buried under "Game Development", "Board & Card Games", and "Role-playing Games", so you don't see it unless you scroll down.

You encounter a similar problem with several other sites:

- if you are searching for "Seasoned Advice", you won't find it with "Cooking" since it is not referenced in the site's description. In fact, this one is impossible to find as "food" isn't mentioned either.  The only cooking term that you could find the site by is "Chef".
- "Mi Yodeya" also has the same problem since "Judaism" is not mentioned anywhere but the URL.  "Jewish" is mentioned in the description, but has virtually no characters in common with Judaism save the "J".
- Amateur Radio's URL is Ham.SE, so that's another tough one to find.
- Mathematics has a closely related problem since most users who learned UK English might search for "maths", which does not return anything either.

Not all sites have the same problem since the name is close to the URL or the URL is mentioned in the description (for example "Ask Different" references "Apple", "Home Improvement" references "DIY" in the description), but this can make finding specific sites problematic for users who might not be familiar with the boutique name of the site and only know it by the URL.

Can the search be updated to reference the URL, or at least the descriptions also include some reference to the URL Name for all sites to make it easier to find.

Comment: @MartijnPieters oy, missed that one.  But that's closed as a duplicate of the original bug report.  If we're going to close this one, then we need to reopen that one.

Comment: I re-opened it.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Indeed, and Kasra just did so.