# Can we have the UTC time on the inbox as well?

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

Right now the achievements has it, but the inbox does not.

[image]

[image]

Considering the two icons are like ten pixels apart its not so hard to open one then the other, but it would still be nice to have the reference in the inbox as well.

Im not sure if this is a dupe. I tried digging thourgh the 70 answers in [The new top bar is out on meta. Consider it a beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta) but couldn't find it.

Comment: sorry but i have to disagree as i see no use for that :? when you hover over the time part in your inbox you get a comment popup with the full date

Comment: While we're at it, what about the SE dropdown? There's space there too. It would be left as the odd one out if it was added to the inbox as well as achievements. There's space in all 3. EDIT: That one doesn't display times, but maybe to keep consistency between the 3 it should be included anyway.

Comment: I was assuming the hot questions were gonna end up there. @GeorgeDuckett I mean, they have to be somewhere

Comment: @TsSkTo no, hot questions are going to a different place, see [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/207503#comment660202_207420)

Comment: @mehow: Not the current date, you don't.

Comment: It's been four years, can someone look at this?

Answer (score 5):

I think it would be neater if the time is simply displayed on the top bar itself.

**Rationale:** The display of UTC time is **not related to** *Achievements* in particular, even though it's most used in relation to gaining reputation. The time is related to *Stack Exchange* **as a whole**, and should therefore be shown in a place representative of that.

Time is **not** displayed, when none of the three panels is open:

[image: UTC Time not shown in top bar when none of the panels are open.]

When I open any of the panels, the time should **fade in** at the top bar. It should remain shown when I switch between panels. When I close the panel, the time should **fade out**.

> [image: UTC Time shown in top bar when Sites panel is open.]

> [image: UTC Time shown in top bar when Inbox panel is open.]

> [image: UTC Time shown in top bar when Achievements panel is open.]

**As an advantage,** the time could also fade in when the mouse pointer is hovering above it, and fade out when pointer is moved away. Like a spoiler *(as shown with fade effects on desktop site)*:

> 09:20 UTC

[image: UTC Time shown in top bar when mouse pointer hovers over its display area.]

**PS:** I felt the term *time* (as in `UTC TIME 09:20`) was redundant, so I favored the format `09:20 UTC` in my mock-ups.

Comment: @downvoter Can I know why?

Comment: Seriously, what is with the down votes after the edit? Is it the spoilers hiding the images? I didn't want to clutter the post with too many images shown at a time, but I also didn't want to rely on links!

Comment: +1 because of "The display of UTC time is __not related__ to *Achievements*" but -1 because I don't think the time is important enough to display constantly as a top-level element (or whatever the proper UX term for that is) for a net 0. I guess that's the motivation for the second half of the answer, but I suspect the fading logic would just confuse people.

Comment: @Pops You got it wrong. It would **not be displayed constantly**, but only when the panels are opened. Please see my answer again. Also, as for the fade-in on hover, it is just an added bonus for those who want to see the timestamp without opening any panel. *Happy new year!*