# Display most frequently-used sites on Site Switcher

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

Since [this suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207470) is locked, I decided to give it some visibility by reposting here. A quote:

> The sites I have high rep on are not necessarily the ones I'm using frequently.

Response to [a Comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209984/display-most-frequently-used-sites-on-site-switcher?noredirect=1#comment672919_209984): I was thinking if, for example, [the activity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147166/tshepang?tab=activity) for the past week (or month) can be used to decide which sites get listed on top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are planning to allow you to edit the list and order things however you want. That should take care of your concerns.