# My username instead of my Gravatar in the top bar

Tags: feature-request, design, usability, top-bar

A minor suggestion, but I actually loved having my username there. This would make icon size issues I've seen others complain about simply... go away.

I stole this idea from [this locked post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209643/147166).

Comment: Are you going to re-surface every answer you see there that you like?  It's entirely unnecessary; I'm quite sure that the staff has seen each and every one of them already.

Comment: -1 for a [colour of the bike shed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson's_law_of_triviality) request.

Comment: For those who were not watching, here is the other one I re-surfaced: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209984.

Comment: Wow, people are really really unloving this one. I am surprised.

Comment: @TheGrinch The other question is locked with the comment: Please post bugs or concerns as questions tagged [top-bar]. So I don't think this question is unnecessary. I want my username back, too.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I'd really like to add a -1 for giving a bull shed comment...

Comment: @stefan.s The "Colour of the bikeshed" is something where everyone has an opinion about, everyone has a lot of different opinions and most importantly, something that isn't a significant improvement to the site. Even if someone likes the change, there will be someone who says: "Hey! I actually liked the icon. Give me an option to get it back" and someone who says "Hey! I don't like the username -or- the icon. Give me an option to display my email/random unicorn". Does it matter for SO? Not really. Bikeshedding-discussions are counter-productive, and that's why I vote them down.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I liked having my name in the top bar. It was a nice visual indication that I was logged into the site.

I also liked having a ♦ as a visual indication that I was a moderator on a site.

Now my name is gone, there is only my avatar, which at this size is just some random unrecognizable picture. (Ok, more recognizable than the [square bra](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/207461#comment662122_207461).)

Please bring back the user name.

To make room, you can take out the list of badges. I never saw the point of these. Reputation, yes, I guess many people like to see it, and for people like me who participate on multiple sites it indirectly tells me which privileges I have on the site. But the badges? They don't change often, they have zero impact, they can stay in the profile page.