# New SE Layout - clicking on rep in banner no longer opens rep changes

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, design, top-bar, navigation

I know, I know... "While we are definitely open to feedback, try using the new design for a little."

Seems that the separate navigation that was previously provided by the profile photo (to profile) and reputation (to profile reputation changes) has been replaced with a single link to profile.

Please bring back the separate nav for rep!

Comment: You could click the site icons in achievements dropdown to get there.

Comment: Can you comment on the *why*? What's missing from the achievements dropdown that you constantly have to go to the profile's rep tab?

Comment: @3ventic True - hadn't stumbled on that yet. Takes twice as many clicks, but I could get used to it. But since real estate is still dedicated to displaying our Reputation, why not let it keep being used for nav?

Comment: I'd like to see comments on *why it's not being used* for navigation.

Comment: @balpha - Not much missing, just different. But like brasofilo says - "why change"? I do find the profile rep tab a bit easier to see and manipulate on my mobile device. (Although the ach dd is fairly usable.)

Comment: [THIS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta) would have saved a lot of traffic today, don't you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because user testing found linking to recent reputation changes as a primary use case of the top nav one of the major changes was to add a whole new menu tab *just* to show recent reputation changes, while also having links to the reputation tab on the profile for further reading.

The functionality wasn't removed; it was greatly expanded on.

Comment: The fact that there is no simple summary is not helpful; it is not specific to the site I'm looking at. This is a retrograde step and reduces the usability. The vote summary (as in, votes I've made) was useful; the instant click to activity was useful; the reputation changes per site were better as far as I'm concerned. The new one really doesn't cut it for me. It includes information from sites I'm not interested in at the moment (when I want to know about other sites, I'll go visit them). It doesn't include the summary information. I didn't like it in beta on Meta; I really dislike it on SO.

Comment: FWIW, @Jonathan, you can jump directly to your site-specific reputation page by clicking the site's icon at the top of the reputation drop-down. I miss the clickable number too (waaaay too much muscle memory to re-learn quickly - you don't want to know how many times I've tried to go to meta and ended up somewhere else...) but there is a lot of good functionality packed into the new UI.

Comment: The new functionality is not the old functionality, and the useful parts of the old functionality are not available from the new, especially not as a hover item. I wouldn't mind it being a clickable item; I do mind it not being there. **And** I want to make it very clear to anyone from SE (the corporation) that there are at least some very, *very*, **very**, ***very*** disgruntled people out here who do not like the 'change for the sake of change' stuff. (Add to that the unpleasant colour scheme and we're into another discussion, but I'll live with that. The functional changes are not better.)