# Site search in new multicollider should favor titles

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange-button, top-bar

I type in 'phys' in the site search box, clearly looking for the **Physics** site, but since astrophysics is in the description of the **Astronomy** site, and that site is earlier alphabetically, it shows up first. I don't think that should happen.

[image: Sorry, no access to MS paint.]

Comment: This looks... [familiar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207442/102937).

Comment: *My Dupe sense is tingling*.

Comment: To be fair @TheGrinch, this one's justified... typing _"physic"_ doesn't even get me the ability to view physics... people are likely to be searching on site name occasionally and it could have a higher weighting.

Comment: I'm working on this one now, wanted to get the bar out while there were still a few hours to observe load today though.

Comment: @NickCraver I know you are all over this so just a suggestion in case you weren't already doing it: Site Search should also look at the top [n] tags on each site.  For example, a search for 'camping' should return The Great Outdoors even though 'camping' is not in the title/description.

Comment: @DavidHAust this is a simple JavaScript thing, maybe at some point we'll add more stuff to it, but the display would have to include those elements for it to many any sense

Comment: @TheGrinch I confess my interest waned after reading the first "answer" on that page, so I didn't see the other. Should I keep this question?

Comment: @NickCraver Fair call if it's just JavaScript. An idea to address the display issue for when 'some point' comes around...Do the search on the tags and if a match is made you could append ' including [tag name]' or something similar to the end of the site description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The search should now favor titles.  This went out in a build a few hours ago.  If you see any glitches please report them here.  It's currently a very simple algorithm: show title matches, then description matches, both groups still in their respective orders.  There is no "score" involved, just a case insensitive match in play as it's totally JavaScript based.

Comment: can you favor the beginning of titles? If I search "phy", cryptography, photography, and philisophy are above physics

Comment: @JakobWeisblat yeah I plan to favor: exact, then starts with, then titles, then description - will be tweaking it today

Comment: @JakobWeisblat better behavior going out next build, more to come.