# Make the top bar inbox dropdown click target easier to access

Tags: feature-request, design, usability, top-bar

The link to the list of sites, which I use very occasionally, is about 140 pixels wide and in a nice accessible location near the left margin (though for some reason not flush left).

The link to the inbox, which I use very often, is about 35 pixels wide and awkwardly located in a middling location.

(It also suffers from having a [square bra](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/207461#comment662122_207461) for an icon, or [whatever that icon is supposed to represent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/207461#comment660447_207461). That  should be changed to something easily recognizable like, say, an envelope.)

This is backward. It's a major drop in usability from the former inbox access which had the inbox as a nice wide button and the first thing on the left (though for some reason not flush left either) whenever messages were pending.

[image: left part of the top bar]

(Greener colors for easy to click, brighter colors for more useful. If you see bright red and dark green, you're doing it wrong. Apologies to the color blind in the audience.)

Please make the inbox button wider. It really needs to be wider than the site list since it's more useful, at least when there are unread messages.

I'm unsure about the achievements button (which also has an unrecognizable graphic — is that a bar chart? What does this have to do with achievements?) since I don't know yet what use that list is.

Comment: The "square bra" is the inbox half of the classic inbox / outbox... boxes - [photo of said inbox](http://msujaws.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/inbox.jpg), though I will admit the square bra has a certain appeal to it... Sponge Bobbete Square Bra?

Comment: Ahhh, it's a square bra. I always though it was a purse/handbag ; )

Comment: @MichaelT I finally get it. I always thought it was a really poorly-drawn icon of an open envelope.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Its just a matter of working at a place where the boxes were common place on the desks of managers... (*shudders* flashbacks... no no no̱̰̗͎̼͛̐ͅ n͚̜͎͍̭͍̞ͪo͎̞ͦ̓ n͔͙͔̗̲̦ͯ̑ö̥͉̖̮̮̙́̌ͣ͐ͅ N̫͇̳̘͛̌ͅO͖̜̼̠̱̦͐ͨ...)