# New inbox graphic

Tags: discussion, design, global-inbox, icons

What is the new Inbox icon ([image]) supposed to represent?

It reminds me of cardboard 3d glasses or oculus rift or even a upside down ( old )telephone. Is it supposed to be a basket of sorts?

Comment: An inbox .... no really.

Comment: An inbox; a plastic tray on a desk..

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=paper+inbox

Comment: One of these things: http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/43000380/images/mcls819q1__2.jpg

Comment: It is supposed to be an inbox in perspective, but it looks more like the back of a station wagon to me.

Comment: It's a 3D inbox. Isn't that obvious :)

Comment: It is an Inbox - as in your title, the inbox icon. http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-a7hb063G8S0/T0akA4KiOMI/AAAAAAAAAJ8/fADhMOVMQjY/s320/inbox.jpg

Comment: [Gilles has been calling it a bra](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210019/179419)... as have [a few others](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta#comment662100_207461).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards [It was Amicable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/207461#comment662100_207461), actually. But I liked the name and decided to reuse it. The actual answer is that [it's a letter tray](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/207461#comment660623_207461). I didn't get it until someone told me.

Comment: And this whole time I thought it was an open envelope.

Comment: It's an *envelope*?  Wow...not how I interpreted it, but it makes sense once pointed out.  Icons are difficult...very difficult. And while I'm at it, I don't like the birthday cake, or the suggestion that scores might go down enough to be noticeable.

Comment: Look at the white part, not the black part.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image]

You put papers in it. And you can [buy it on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007KLTDA).

Comment: You sell your inbox?! For how much? ;)

Comment: @Undo Never crossed my mind. Its been a while since I used paper.

Comment: @self. To be honest, I've never really put much thought into it myself before now either :)

Comment: Should be more like this: imo http://i.imgur.com/lDJKnBq.jpg

Comment: @self. Meh, not simple enough. Less is more.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't look right.  Where's the cat?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a desktop inbox metaphor

[image]

Comment: What speaks against using the old envelope icon again? It is far less likely to be mistaken for something else.

Comment: Huh? Were you looking for [this](http://img1.etsystatic.com/017/0/6379238/il_340x270.500113521_ln21.jpg)?

Comment: Ok, now I need to admit that a wooden inbox looks like a car in a `20px` icon.

Comment: The letter tray metaphor is fine. It's too bad that the icon isn't recognizable as a letter tray.

Answer (score -1):

At first, I was thinking a smartphone:

[image: iPhone]

Comment: Nope. Wrong object.