# Bring back my name to the top bar

Tags: feature-request, design, usability, top-bar

I liked having my name in the top bar. It was a nice visual indication that I was logged into the site.

I also liked having a ♦ as a visual indication that I was a moderator on a site.

Now my name is gone, there is only my avatar, which at this size is just some random unrecognizable picture. (Ok, more recognizable than the [square bra](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/207461#comment662122_207461).)

Please bring back the user name.

To make room, you can take out the list of badges. I never saw the point of these. Reputation, yes, I guess many people like to see it, and for people like me who participate on multiple sites it indirectly tells me which privileges I have on the site. But the badges? They don't change often, they have zero impact, they can stay in the profile page.

Comment: Don't really have an opinion on the diamond as I don't have one (can anyone lone me one for testing?), guess it could be put in there somewhere, but for showing your name I don't see how useful that is really; surely that changes less than the badges.

Comment: I'd personally rather see my badges than my name. If frequency of change is an argument here, my name changes even less often. ;)

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett The user name isn't about things that change (though some people do have multiple accounts). It's about having an indication that I'm logged in (which does change, depending on browser and network flakyness). The avatar just doesn't cut it, especially mine which is rather dark and doesn't have much contrast with the top bar's dark gray.

Comment: IMO the avatar is enough of an indication that I'm logged in. Agree to disagree I guess. :)

Comment: There is a diamond as well, it's just to the left of your gravatar