# Add "main" link to "help" drop menu on "meta"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, top-bar

Sounds complicated, is simple. When you get to `meta` through the link in the `help` drop menu, you can't get back to `main` the same way. Therefore I suggest adding a 4th item to that drop menu on meta sites, which could read something like:

> **Get back to the main site**
>
> You're on Meta site now

(Excuse me, English is not my first language and it might use some more clever help text.)

It was pointed out before on [meta.TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4008/more-problems-with-the-new-site-redesign) that this assymetry can be confusing. I'm posting the request here since it should apply network-wide.

Comment: The way I see it, Meta is a "Help" resource for SO, but SO is NOT a "Help" resource for Meta. Therefore, I disagree.

Comment: @JerryDodge On the other hand, the current assymetry _is_ strange and confusing. When you click `Tour` or `Help center`, you still can get back to main by clicking the site banner/logo. This is not the case for `Meta`, which causes the troubles. IMHO what I propose is a good solution for this assymetry.

Comment: Maybe the meta logo should lead to the main site?

Comment: @JanDvorak Definitely not.

Comment: There *is* symmetry there; on main, you see 'Meta', on meta you see 'What is Meta'. They both point to the help resource for the current site, the plate *about* the current site.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The fact that things are symmetrical by the `x`-axis doesn't mean they're well symmetrical by the `y`-axis. You speak about `x` and I point out `y`. Honestly, can you point out any real cons of the link being there?

Comment: This is the *help* menu; the Stack Exchange drop-down on the left also provides links to both the main and the meta sites. Why do we need another link?

Comment: @MartijnPieters By the same argument: why do we need two `meta` links and only one `main` link? Ok, the answer can be: "Because we want to bring people to meta." However, don't we also "want to bring people from meta back to main"?

Comment: @tohecz Sure.  You're proposing the help link be changed to point to SO, but there isn't help information about Meta on SO, so people won't find help there.  Not being able to find help there seems like a good reason to not link people there for help.

Comment: @tohecz We don't have two meta links.  We have one link to meta and one link to the help page, that simply happens to be hosted on meta.

Comment: @Servy Yet, when someone clicks the link that you don't call a link, he get's lost since he can't get back. So, in the end, he might need help in getting to `main`. And as well, considering how often someone posts a main Q to meta, having a notice in the help menu, that real questions should go on main, wouldn't harm. (But as I said, I'm not English enough to find good words for that.)

Comment: @tohecz: what evidence do you have that people get lost? Is there an actual problem here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters [Have you clicked the link that is in the question text, please?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4008/more-problems-with-the-new-site-redesign)

Comment: @tohecz If you think it should be easier to get back to the main site from the meta site that's one thing that makes sense, and I'd be willing to consider methods of doing that.  Changing the "help" link is not an appropriate way of doing that though; simply because there are no help links about meta on the main site (nor should there be; they belong on meta).

Comment: @Servy Well, IMHO it fits there. Even if `main` doesn't provide `help` as a 1-800-xxx help-line does, it provides help in getting where you want to. In the sense that if you get to meta, you find a way to main there. I don't think that once someone is on meta, he would click "Main site" link if he really seeks help (therefore the link wouldn't cause any harm). He will more likely click "Help Center". However, if he doesn't think of clicking "StackExchange", because it's not enough a button for him (or whatever, you know as much as I do how people get lost on SE), he'll never get back to main.

Comment: @tohecz I can't possibly imagine how someone would imagine that clicking "help" on meta would take them to the main site.  You might think that, but I can't imagine many others thinking the same thing.  Main is not where you go to get help about meta.  My guess is the only reason you're linking the two is because there used to be a link to main where the "help" link is now.  For anyone not used to having that link there, there is no association between the two concepts.

Comment: One anecdote does not a problem make. We need quantitative evidence; one swallow doesn't make it summer, and one person gotten lost because you expected links you found close to the older location to behave the same, doesn't mean there are a lot of people with that problem.

Comment: @Servy The point is that there's no "back" for that one that would be similar to the "forward" one in `help>meta`. It's like a sub-dir with no obvious `..`

Comment: @MartijnPieters Honestly, SE can (put strong bad words here) aboud "quantitative evidence" about the new top-bar. If they want it, just count the number of users upvotind the hatred posts about it on all metas ;)

Comment: @tohecz Which is why I said that if you feel there should be a more obvious mechanism to get back to the main site I could understand it; this just is an entirely inappropriate decision as to how to go about doing that.

Comment: @tohecz: That's not quantitative research, that's populist voting. Only those who care strongly about an issue will put in the effort to shout, and not all those who shout have put thought into the issue.

Comment: @Servy Like "get back to main" close to the top 6 buttons? Yeah, that would be IMHO cool (and I in a sense miss it from the very beginning, with the topbar link being an unnatural substitute), but it means re-designing all 120 (or how many are there) sites, good luck with that.

Comment: @Servy -- since i was the originator of the complaint on meta.tex.sx, i (obviously) agree that having a more obvious mechanism to get back to the main site would be desirable.  i also recognize that newcomers to the site might not have an equally unnerving experience.  but the former facility was very welcome, and thus greatly missed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- i rather resent the implication that i didn't think the matter through thoroughly before posting my question.  admittedly the matter was clouded by other concurrent problems that turned out to be unrelated (but cost nearly two days of lost productive time).  if it's decided this matter is not worth the effort of making changes that will affect all sites, not just the ones that interest me, i can accept that.  but i hope to be able to remain polite while doing so.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: No impoliteness was intended! I am Dutch, which apparently means I am culturally biased towards directness. I did not mean to imply you didn't think things through; I am giving you direct feedback where your proposal is weak. Would you rather I not present arguments that would count against the proposal?

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- thank you for your feedback.  if others do find this to be a problem, i hope they will chime in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure when exactly, but this has already been implemented.