# Two years later: How has moving the Meta link affected Meta usage?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, top-bar, per-site-meta, navigation

Two years ago the link to a site's Meta was moved from an always-visible position in the top bar to subitems in the help and Site Switcher menus, as part of the [top bar redesign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta) progressively rolled out in November and December 2013.

Shog9 quite fairly [noted at the time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210255/understanding-the-significance-of-the-elimination-of-one-click-transfer-between/210261#210261):

> The bigger concern here is that folks who aren't already used to going to meta won't find it. That would be bad. […]
>
> But there's no way to know ahead of time if that concern is warranted. We're now linking to meta from three different locations on every page: the Site Switcher, the Help menu, and the footer. […] This could actually end up improving the ability of folks to find their way in...
>
> The only way to know is to try it and see...

Robert Cartaino [echoed these concerns and the focus on data-driven design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210255/understanding-the-significance-of-the-elimination-of-one-click-transfer-between/210261#comment674239_210261) in a comment:

> My main concern of removing the "support forum" from the main menu was one of ***discoverability***. I'm still a bit nervous that, if incoming users don't know the feature exists, meta will become a fading legacy system used only by the old-timers who still know its there. I'm sure we'll be watching for such behavior changes closely, *fingers crossed*.

Now that two years have passed, what does the data look like? Has moving the link to Meta positively or negatively (or “other”) affected sites' Meta traffic and usage patterns?

- Do we have more or fewer users per capita visiting sites' Metas now?
- Volume aside, is the kind of traffic driven to Meta different — say, a change in the ratio of new and old users?
- Has the Help menu entry driven more new users to visit Meta for support issues?
- Which of the three paths (switcher, help, footer*) get used most, by which kinds of users?
- Do the numbers vary by site at all?
- Other metrics that I don't even know to ask about for lack of UX knowledge? :)

The proof, as they say, is in the pudding! How has it turned out?

<sup>* <strike>Hm, there does not appear to be a link to a site's Meta in the footer anymore.</strike> Ah, it's the **feedback** link.</sup>

Comment: Meta is, in some sense, also linked from user profile pages ("meta user"), though I don't think that does much for discoverability.  (I don't know if that link is there if the user has never visited meta and thus hasn't created a meta user, for example.)

Comment: @Jeffrey indeed, that link is not visible unless the user visited the meta site, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/users/1788/matt-brewer.