# Have Rep Dropdown show Non-Rep votes

Tags: feature-request, top-bar, information-display, achievements-dialog, reputation-display

In the prior top bar, the rep dropdown would show you the votes you got after you hit the rep cap, just with no rep showing.  The new dropdown for the new top bar no longer shows you that you received those votes.  I end up having to go to my profile and hit the reputation tab to see if I got any upvotes after I hit the rep cap.

Please put this functionality back into the rep dropdown.

Note, that this also applies to up and down CW votes.

Comment: I don't recall after-rep-cap upvotes ever showing in the dropdown; I always looked and look in my reputation tab for those.

Comment: __Not a dupe__, that one is about the green icon, I'm talking about the dropdown showing the list of rep changes per post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I remember it, it just showed no rep, but I was able to click on the post link to go look at it.

Comment: Don't think it's a dupe, voting to reopen.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It is actually a dupe of [this proposition](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207972/174490) on the top bar post.

Comment: @insertcleverxmasname, yes, you're right that it's the same thing proposed in that answer.  Many answers get made into feature-requests later (though I didn't take that route).  Too bad they locked the question that's on so we can't upvote that answer anymore.

Comment: @LanceRoberts And many questions get closed as duplicate because of this top bar post.

Comment: Yeh, it was maybe ok when they were closing them in the weeks following the question, but after it was done and locked, nothing should be closed as a dupe of that one anymore.  The feature is out, and now we can make questions requesting changes to it.

Comment: @insertcleverxmasname true but I agree with Lance here. The top bar is now "solid", all requests there that were not done should be made into new, separate, questions. (I think most already did)