# Top bar color chooser needs happier colors

Tags: feature-request, top-bar, unicoins

When I saw the “Top bar color chooser” power-up, I immediately hoped I could bring some color into StackOverflow and make the top bar pink or rainbow-colored. So I spent a significant part of my day hurting my mouse by farming those 80 unicoins.

But then I was presented by this super disappointing selection of possible colors.

[image: Super disappointing boring top bar colors]

I believe those colors are super boring and far too dark. It feels like the StackExchange team is against happyness. So I would suggest adding a few more color schemes to it. Because **just look at this fancyness**:

[image: Super fancy rainbow topbar]

Comment: Wow, does nobody really get any of the jokes? Why, oh why, did I bother coming to meta today?

Comment: So Burnt Velvet didn't really do it for you?

Comment: Try adjusting your gamma.

Comment: @AaronBertrand That comment makes me wonder the same about you…?

Comment: @poke I guess. I found humor in the original joke, but that was enough for me. I don't find the endless stream of meta complaints funny. *shrug*

Comment: happier is relative.

Comment: @Jin: Spoken like a true designer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey /tip my fedora to you good sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this was made especially for [those who wanted different colour schemes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207439/152515):

> Could we have a colour scheme that doesn't burn my eyes?
>
> Pretty much anything that isn't black (or just off black)

Now you have new, colourful options other than off-black!

Comment: Bingo, #thatsthejoke. :)

Answer (score 2):

Does dark grey look ugly?  Well here's a UserScript to make the topbar a different color, the *best* color, *black!*

```
$('.topbar').css('background-color', 'black');
```

Comment: Actually, I think it should just be `$('.topbar').css('background-color', 'black');`

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Sorry, that doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure? It works fine for me.

Comment: Ok I was testing in chrome beta, sorry!